# Gradle error after adding Google API

Tags: gradle, sdk, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, google-sheets-api

I am trying to develop an app with one activity pulling data from a google worksheet. I am following the quickstart guide in

[Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android)

However, in step 4, I did not want to replace all my gradle settings with their suggestions since I am already developing with higher SDK version so I simply add the necessary compile lines from their dependencies so my gradle.app looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.erik.icaregg"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev38-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I tried to run the app or sync project with gradle the build always ends up with an error and the message is

```
Error:14:21:26.378 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
14:21:26.396 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:21:26.396 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:21:26.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:21:26.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:21:26.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
14:21:26.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Dependency Error. See console for details.
14:21:26.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:21:26.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:21:26.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
```

The error is not shown on the workspace itself so I am really confused where the error is located. Can anyone help me out on this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encountered this first... @gbhall posted an awesome answer here

[Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347326/errorconflict-with-dependency-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305)