# How to use YouTube API V3 to get Channels

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I want to use the YouTube API V3 to get channels by their name, their subs count, videos count and views count to display them in a CardView (which I already have).

How to add the api to my build.gradle?

If I add `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev182-1.22.0'` to my `build.gradle(Module app)` then I get:

> Error: Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>
> Warning: WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

How to use the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357786/7337723)
Two dependencies are trying to use different versions of third dependency.

Comment: Thank you, I can use the API now.

Comment: Accept the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: It's working, but I still don't know how to get channel subs count, videos count and views count to display them in a CardView.

Comment: Go through Udacity's Android Courses. Follow projects on GitHub like this one https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist