# Android: force gradle to include only one version of a library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-dependencies, support-v4

I use `'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'` in my `build.gradle` but when explore external libraries I see two version of support-v4 library (23.3.0 & 24.0.0). How can I find which dependency use support-v4:24.0.0 library?  How can I force gradle to only add version 23.3.0?

[image: external libraries image]

this is my dependency list in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile ('com.nightonke:wowoviewpager:1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
    compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/btsdk.jar')
    compile project(':zxing_barcode') // this project include the same version of support-v4 library
    compile project(':cropper')// this project include the same version of support-v4 library
    compile project(':taptargetview')// this project include the same version of support-v4 library
    compile ('me.cheshmak:analytics:1.0.28'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    compile ('com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0@aar'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.11@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile ('cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:1.5.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
}
```

I use `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'` to avoid others adding support library but no change happened.

Comment: I think, cleaning the project or invalidating cache and restart should help you.

Comment: No, I deleted build files, clean project and rebuilt but it is still there.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I can't add comment so I link here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357786/3442734

use:

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Still getting conflict with another version.