# Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating Android Studio from **Canary 3** to **Canary 4**, the following error is thrown at the build time.

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-support-v4' has different version for the compile (25.2.0) and runtime (26.0.0-beta2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution.

I ran a complete search throughout the project and the version `25.1.0` is no where used.

**App-build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}


buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation project(':core')
implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:7.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

**Library-build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation files('libs/model.jar')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0-beta2'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'

}
```

**Note:** Project was building fine in Canary 3

Comment: i was also facing the same issue ,  as i am using two modules in my app ,  so make sure you are using the same version code for all the gradle files.

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254

Answer (score 139):

Use this code in your buildscript (build.gradle root):

```
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "version which should be used - in your case 26.0.0-beta2"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, remember to change details.useVersion to a version number, if you just copy & paste it will fail

Comment: Making sure to include the `!details.requested.name.contains('multidex')` really helped me out.

Comment: I tried this, but it only worked for the com.android.support conflict. It didn't work for the com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics conflict. The 'contains' seems to match too many packages. I used the simpler solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404308/android-force-gradle-to-include-only-one-version-of-a-library) instead for all of the conflicts and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @user3908686 solved the problem but please explain , why we need to add this??

Comment: This works perfectly with flutter projects with lots of plugins that have their own dependencies.

Comment: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android`. Sadly, doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Worked for me, don't forget to 'details.useVersion "26.0.0-beta2"'

Answer (score 84):

I had the same error, what solve my problem was. In my **library** instead of using compile or implementation i use "api". So in the end my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
api files('libs/model.jar')
testApi 'junit:junit:4.12'
api 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.0-beta2'
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
api 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0-beta2'

api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
api 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
api 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
api 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
}
```

You can find more info about "api", "implementation" in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/3479489

Comment: All of android studio recommends using implementation.. And this offbeat solution works. Google engineers at android studios need a lesson to learn from the world. What a frustrating tool

Comment: it doesn´t solve the problem , the message says: "Android dependency '...............' has different version for the compile"

Comment: @KeithLoughnane This is not bad practice, is the correct way to do it and  the way the documentation recommend

Comment: @YayoArellano implementation is what is recommended with judicious use of api where absolutely required. This is throw everything at the wall and see what sticks programming. Some of those may need api but not all of them. You are exposing far too much.

Comment: While it may prevent the error, this is a *hacky workaround* and not a proper solution! The only thing that using `api` over `implementation` does is to *expose your library dependencies* to the app project _even if the app project does not need the dependency at all_ (and as a side-effect pinning the dependencies to that version). Use the dependency resolution strategy instead!

Comment: @Siddharth In rather practical terms... using `api` in a library/feature module makes sense, when the main module used `implementation`, which then has to become `api` there, too. It's merely good for sharing dependencies among different modules.

Answer (score 27):

You should be able to see exactly which dependency is pulling in the odd version as a transitive dependency by running the correct `gradle -q dependencies` command for your project as described here:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies

Once you track down what's pulling it in, you can add an exclude to that specific dependency in your gradle file with something like:

```
implementation("XXXXX") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
}
```

Comment: Hi,I ran the gradle dependency command and I'm posting the screenshot url here, imgur.com/dL35BaN. I never use Firebase in my project. Added that line in gcm, it didn't work though

Comment: @DroidLearner I might be missing something, but I don't see any reference to com.android.support:support-compat in the screenshot you posted.  Also there is a warning in that screen shot that refers to a 'compile' configuration which I don't see present in your gradle file in the OP.  it's likely that it's coming from the :core submodule.  Can you post the relevant gradle information from there?

Comment: Hi, posting you the entire gradle files with dependency tree here.. 
app gradle file -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93affc0d75eb96b59f9fde51332b9716
core gradle file ->https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c85031f26ff766109061ab1f00b833d
dependency tree ->https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71dd33b6fa4dc63dd357889e8aff01ee

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like the older version of the library is being pulled in by firebase, which in turn is a transitive dependency of gms.  You can likely get this working by adding:  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2' before any other dependency.  Long term turning off transitive dependencies in favor of being explicit or using a resolutionStrategy (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) is likely a better approach.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow managed to fix the transitive dependency. Gradle build succeeded. 
At runtime its showing errors with all  library classes. 
error: package retrofit2 does not exist
error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
error: package com.google.gson does not exist.
At compile time it didn't show any errors.

Answer (score 16):

After a lot of time and getting help from a friend who knows a lot more than me about android:
app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    // org.gradle.caching = true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cryptoviewer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 196
        versionName "16.83"
        // ndk {
        //     abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        // }
    }
```

and dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
   //...
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0" // <= YOU CARE ABOUT THIS
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

in build.gradle

```
allprojects {
   //...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0"
    }
```

in gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableAapt2=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M
```

Comment: `resolutionStrategy.force` was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The answer for me was to also add this to my `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
      if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
          details.useVersion "26.1.0"
      }
  }
}
```

In my case, it was nessisary to enclose the resolution strategy in a `configurations.all { .. }` block. I placed the `configurations.all` block directly into my `app/build.gradle` file (ie `configurations.all` was not nested in anything else)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and I fixed it by adding this code to the ***gradle.properties*** file.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

Add the follow line in `app/build.gradle` in dependencies section:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
```

or `:27.1.1` in my case

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in your project level build.gradle file.

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "version which should be used - in your case 28.0.0-beta2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Code :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone getting this dependency issue in 2019, update Android Studio to 3.4 or later

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by upgrading my gradle dependency in the android/build.gradle file: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' (I was previously on version 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by following what Eddi mentioned above,

```
 resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Switching my conflicting dependencies from implementation to api does the trick.  Here's a good article by mindorks explaining the difference.

https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa

Edit:

Here's my dependency resolutions as well

```
 subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                    details.useVersion "28.0.0"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-base')) {
                    details.useVersion "15.0.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-tasks')) {
                    details.useVersion "15.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

See in your library projects make the **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** version to same level as your application is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}
```

also make all dependencies to same level

Answer (score 1):

I comment out `//api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'` it worked for me after sync

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines in your build.gradle file

resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0-beta2"

resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was having two different versions of the below implementation in two different modules, So i changed both implementation to versions ie : 6.0.2 and it worked. You may also need to write dependency resolution see the accepted answer.

**app module**

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
```

**commons module**

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force
        //"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
        //here put the library that made the error with the version you want to use
    }
```

add this to gradle (project) inside `allprojects`

Answer (score -7):

Replace a hard coded version to +
example:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
```

Comment: Not exactly best practice as this can cause a library to kind of run away from you. Ex. They change the way things are done in a new version and all of a sudden your code doesn't work. While you should strive to use the latest version, you should manually set the version number after testing it first to prevent unwanted crashes and bugs.

Comment: Not a good practice. In addition to what @JonahStarling said, it will also affect Gradle build performance if the offline feature is turned off.