# React-native: Android dependency has different version

Tags: android, react-native, dependencies

I am getting the following error

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (25.3.1) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

The following is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hauz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'

    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            // The order in which you list these repositories matter.
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-share')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native"
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295415/you-should-manually-set-the-same-version-via-dependencyresolution

Comment: @GabrielDevillers, i tried that. But it didn't work :(