# Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (16.1.0) classpath

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm getting error after adding below new `Places API` dependency in `build.gradle` as `Android Places SDK` had been deprecated.

**Error**:

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has
>   different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (16.1.0)
>   classpath. You should manually set the same version via
>   DependencyResolution

I have also updated the google services version from `3.2.1` to `4.2.0` in project level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
    ...
}
```

In app level `build.gradle`. I have added new `Places API` dependency and commented old one, I have also used other services like location and map in project see below

```
 dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0" // new
    // implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0" //deprecated
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using dependency resolution, one can force Gradle to package a specific version:

```
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0") {
    force = true
}
```

Comment: I have tried you solution but not succeed yet, even I don't have dependency like `xxx:play-services-base`

Answer (score 0):

After following lots of answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409979/3251783) helped me!

set `resolutionStrategy` in project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
  ...
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
  }
  ...
}
```