# I can no longer build my project in android studio, get a Android dependency error

Tags: javascript, android

I did someething to my project.  I think it was wghen I was trying to clean up the code and moved somne of the files from  my app to a share module.
Android studio ver 3.0.1

When I try to build the project I get the following error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout' has different version for the compile (1.0.2) and runtime (1.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Comment: Post your both `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to invalidate caches:
File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart... --> Invalidate and Restart.