# Flutter failed to build with map-view plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

I try to add google map to my flutter app using the map_view plugin.
But when I try to build the app I have this error :

*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-fragment' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution*

I follow all instructions in the plugin installation guide, and also generate an API key in the google console for Map android SDK.
I added all information in the manifest file :
- 2 lines for permissions
- 2 lines with metada including one with the API key generated just before on google console
- 1 line for activity

I try to build without adding any code regarding the map, normaly I believe that it should work, I mean I configure it but don't import the map in my code, just try to build.

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix that ?

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime

Comment: Thank for your answer, I came from JS to flutter without any background in android App. But I didn't find any of my files with dependancies using implementation, maybe it's different with flutter

Comment: It's fine, no worries. Please try the suggestion from the linked question and report back about your progress or new errors.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but in fact I can't find anywhere in my project something that I can replace with 'API' instead of 'Implementation' or 'compile'.. In my flutter project the only thing I had for dependencies is in my /Android/build.gradle :     `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
    }`      I tried to replace classpath with 'api' but build still failed.

Comment: Well, thank you Günter, i found where to modify it, it is in 'External libraries'. I was trying in VSC instead of Android studio. Now I can build without errors. 'External libraries' was not displayed in VSC. Many thank