# Exception while building a Flutter application

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to build [this](https://github.com/rohan20/flutter-chat-app.git) Flutter app cloned from GitHub.

After I resolved all the dependency errors, I see the following failure :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
s
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Gradle build failed: 1
```

I am stuck with this problem. Can someone help me out ?

The current versions of dependencies on my machine are as follows :

```
  image_picker: ^0.4.10
  google_sign_in: ^3.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.20
  firebase_database: ^1.0.4
  firebase_storage: ^1.0.2
```

Comment: One of those should help   - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020#issuecomment-380178542
  - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20511
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you,its working now:)