# Wix navigation library module does not add to my project with running npm install --save react-native-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, installation, navigation

I am trying to add **Wix navigation library** to my project according to  https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing but when i run the `npm install --save react-native-navigation` command in terminal and then i open my android project in android studio, i don't see any library module for navigation in my project. But the name of react-native-navigation will appear in **package.json** file.

here is my **package.json** file:

```
      {
  "name": "PleaseAnswer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: you should run `react-native link` and check again.

Comment: I did so but it does not work.

Comment: then you need to add the module yourself, sometimes automatic linking fail. Please follow the steps given in the github repo to install manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Android`: 
  if you're using V2 version than `react-native link` won't automatically link your package to android. I would recommend you to follow docs https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing
- `iOS`: I recommend you to use `cocoapods` for iOS configuration
   Add `pod 'ReactNativeNavigation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-navigation'` in your podfile and run `pod install`

Comment: I have done exactly like the link you've sent. But when I run 'npm install --save react-native-navigation ' command the module does not add to my project. It means that the installation is not successful. I have spent 5 days on it...please save my life.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are saying. `npm install --save react-native-navigation` does not automatically link package to your native folders. Did you configure in android and ios folder?

Comment: Finally I could solve it. I did all the steps before and the package library added to my project  but it didn't work and the react-native didn't recognized react-native-navigation. last night I did all the steps again and I ran the command in android studio terminal (after doing all steps) to fix my problem but the package disappear! I think it was a wrong job! anyway the real problem was the conflict between compile and run-time versions. I found my answer in this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime)