# Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (27.0.1) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I just used this flutter package location and the application was fine before i add the package but as soon as i installed from pubspec then immediately shows

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (27.0.1) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

as error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by dding this to build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Happy to hear if helped to someone