# Failed to resolve module 'react-native-google-place-picker'

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, react-native

When I install the [react-native-google-place-piker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-place-picker) module, then following error ouccur:

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps' has
>   different version for the compile (8.4.0) and runtime (16.0.0)
>   classpath. You should manually set the same version via
>   DependencyResolution

See the attached image:

[image]

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: A similar question about the "Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime" with many answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be clear on my answer because there is not much information.

I created a repo with react-native-google-place-picker & react-native-maps, but the configuration is only for Android.

You can go and see how to implement both libraries without conflicts.

[git repo](https://github.com/DimitrisTzimikas/react-native-maps-places-demo)

**Edit**

You also have to change the libraries modules in node_modules.

On react-native-google-place-picker, I changed the build.gradle file (node_modules/react-native-google-place-picker/android/build.gradle)

On react-native-maps the same file but it is on different director (node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle)

Instructions on README.md

Comment: I think this answer is too broad. If you want to help it is better to answer to the specific question.

Comment: @No_D can you tell witch dependencies are those who have the conflict? Of post the package.json