# Build with exception "Android dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' has different version for the compile (1.0.1) and runtime (1.0.2) classpath"

Tags: flutter

**Build failed with an exception:**

> What went wrong:
>        Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>        Android dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' has different version
>    for the compile (1.0.1) and runtime (1.0.2)
>    classpath. You should manually set the same version via
>    DependencyResolution

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.292], locale en-US)
 [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
 [√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
 [√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2)
 [√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: This `stackoverflow` answer will be helpful as there are several heavily upvoted answers, which will give you many ways to solve your problem :                                                                                         [Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Please try by Adding following code to your `android/build.gradle` file

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know is it worked for you. [This documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) will helps you

Hope this will helps you

Comment: I fixed after breaking update to support AndroidX. Thank you so much.

Comment: I mean the issue gone after I merge to support Android-X

Comment: @NateZheng ok thanx

Answer (score 0):

just add below code in build.gradle

```
repositories { maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } }
```