# Android Dependency showing error "has different version for compile and runtime" after adding flutter_local_notifications in flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

After I added **flutter_local_notifications 0.5.2** in flutter dependencies, Android dependency is showing error "has different version for compile and runtime"

I referred this answer [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47383261/10471480)

After that I added this to build.gradle

```
subprojects {
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.slidingpanelayout'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.fragment'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.cursoradapter'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.lifecycle'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.swipefreshlayout'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.loader'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.lifecycle'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.coordinatorlayout'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.drawerLayout'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.legacy'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.customview'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "1.0.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.arch.core'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "2.0.0"
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see many are facing dependency problem.
After I add another again I get dependency error.
I am exhausted adding sooo many `if` statements.

Any help will be really appreciated.