# Error: Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime classpath

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build

I have a ionic cordova project.
I use the following command to build my app:

```
ionic cordova build android -- --xwalk64bit --release
```

I get this error:
Android dependency `dependencyName` has different version for the compile `Vx` and runtime `Vy` classpath.

I tried these solutions:

[Android dependency has different version for the compile and runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653261/android-dependency-has-different-version-for-the-compile-and-runtime)

The only solution that half works is adding implementation to the dependencies.
However when i launch the build command cordova replaces the name and version of my packages by 27.+:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0"
```

by

```
implementation27.+"
implementation27.+"
implementation27.+"
implementation27.+"
implementation27.+"
implementation27.+"
```

Then the build fails with a parsing error.

Using:

```
allprojects {
   //...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
   // etc.
    }
}
```

doesn't work.
Using:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
      if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
          details.useVersion "26.1.0"
      }
  }
}
```

doesn't work either.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you managed to solve it already?

Comment: I build with ionic then Ctrl+Z in android studio to revert the versions and build...
Basically once the assets are build with ionic you ignore the error and pursue build in android studio.
If you can't figured it out let me know more precisely what is your issue.

Comment: I had this cordova-android-support-gradle-release plugin installed. I was able to build everything removing it and also removing duplicated java files under platform/android/CordovaLib project. Solved this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891957/d8-program-type-already-present-org-apache-cordova-buildhelper?noredirect=1#comment100346521_56891957

Comment: Nice, I have this plugin too I think, I'll check if this works w/o it.

Comment: I also had another plugin which was onesignal-cordova-plugin that states it does the same of cordova-android-support-gradle-release in one of its submodules.. so I was in a bit of a mess lol

Comment: I have the same plugin installed too. Thanks for your input.