# D8: Program type already present: org.apache.cordova.BuildHelper

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

While running $ ionic cordova build android the build fails.

Tried to install the npm plugin cordova-android-support-gradle-release but got this issue: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/issues/42

There's actually no specific code I've written for this to happen.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: org.apache.cordova.BuildHelper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562523/777265

Comment: thank you for the comment @DaveAlden. I tried with the cordova-plugin-compat@1.2 and also removing the .java classes but none of the options worked

Comment: @DaveAlden it seems that by deleting those .java files from the CordovaLib it compiles. Would you mind responding so I can approve your answer?

Comment: I don't want to create a duplicate answer or an answer that's simply a link - both are frowned upon by moderators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by removing those duplicated .java classes from the CordovaLib sub project.

Comment: This led me to a solution..I had the CordovaLib specified as a dependency for both the app and a module.  I needed to remove the dependency from the module (which the app was already dependent on)

Comment: @sonyisda1 perhaps you could post the answer? it would be awesome :)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks! I also was able to fix this issue by deleting the following files:

- PermissionHelper.java
- BuildHelper.java

In this folder: ⁨platforms⁩ ▸ ⁨android⁩ ▸ ⁨app⁩ ▸ ⁨src⁩ ▸ ⁨main⁩ ▸ ⁨java⁩ ▸ ⁨org⁩ ▸ ⁨apache⁩

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by removing `cordova-plugin-compat` from my cordova project as it's deprecated and the functionality is now part of cordova for android.

> This plugin is no longer being worked on as the functionality provided by this plugin is now included in cordova-android 6.3.0. You should upgrade your application to use version 1.2.0 of this plugin. It will detect whether or not the plugin is required based on the version of cordova-android your app uses.