# Unable to merge dex gradle 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gson

I am new to Android programming and StackOverflow. I have looked over the rules and already searched the internet and other StackOverflow posts but nothing seemed to fix my problem.

**What I am trying to do**

I am scraping news articles from a website and I want o use the libraries:

- JSoup
- RetroFit
- GSON

**Problem**

When I try install the application to my Android device it fails with the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

**What I have tried from the internet and other StackOverflow posts**

- Tried adding `multiDexEnabled true`to my app level gradle file
- Added this library `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`
- Added this to my manifest file `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`
- Tried updating all libraries to latest versions.
- Tried cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Tried cleaning, invalidating caches and restarting
- Commenting out GSON import and try use GSON imported from one of the other modules
- Forcing GSON version for all

Here is the gradle info log output:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/kim/Documents/Android-Studio-Projects/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/kim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/3edcfe49d2c6053a70a2a47e4e1c2f94998a49cf/gson-2.8.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.8.2.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class]))
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/kim/Documents/Android-Studio-Projects/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/kim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/3edcfe49d2c6053a70a2a47e4e1c2f94998a49cf/gson-2.8.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.8.2.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.shrinkWithProguard(MainDexListTransform.java:232)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:184)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/kim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/3edcfe49d2c6053a70a2a47e4e1c2f94998a49cf/gson-2.8.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.8.2.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.8.2.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
    ... 50 more
```

and finally here is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kim.learning.webscrape"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary= true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

    // JSON Parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

}
```

I am using `Gradle 3.0.1`

if anybody could help i would be very grateful! I've been scratching my head for so long.

Thanks all

**Update 1**

When I comment out the GSON import I then get this error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>     java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/kim/Documents/Android-Studio-Projects/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/kim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/751f548c85fa49f330cecbb1875893f971b33c4e/gson-2.7.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.7.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class]))

**Update 2**

I forced gradle to use one version of gson but get error:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/kim/Documents/Android-Studio-Projects/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/kim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/3edcfe49d2c6053a70a2a47e4e1c2f94998a49cf/gson-2.8.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.8.2.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class]))

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172469/8089770

Comment: can you show your Expose.class

Comment: Internally retrofit2:converter-gson is using  com.google.code.gson you can remove 
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' and try building

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Hi, I haven't defined a Expose class. Do you mean the one that the error is pointing to?

Comment: @SunilKumar I tried that, you can see Update 1 on my post

Comment: Did you clean the project ?

Comment: @SunilKumar Yes i also cleaned

Comment: Ok it looks like org.jsoup:jsoup is  internally using different version of gson  2.7 you need to force it to use single version in gradle

Comment: Try forcing com.google.code.gson:gson version check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404372/4961622

Comment: Didnt work, I updated original post

Comment: I updated the what ive tried section also

Comment: Change all  implementation  to compile in your app level build gradle, it worked for me

Comment: Do you have anything in libs folder?

Comment: @SomeshKumarGurjar I had Selenium for Android in there that I stopped using and forgot to remove it. Just removed it and app installs. Why does that break the whole build? It was a working Selenium lib and it wasnt defined in my app gradle that I use it

Comment: @SomeshKumarGurjar If you add that as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it happens when you add a library dependency like Selenium (internally Selenium JAR uses Gson) in the libs folder. This creates duplication issues as Selenium also uses GSON. 
Remove the responsible library from libs folder. This could be any library in your case it was Selenium.