# Problems downgrading a lib, it keeps cached and crash

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**The problem**

Android studio keeps `picasso:2.71828` in project and its causing problems

**I tried**

I was using
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

due some conflicts with [px-android](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android/) i decided to remove picasso
 or just use picasso:2.5.2

but when i downgrade and sync

the px-android try to use `Picasso.with(context)...` and dont exists on 2.71828, even implementing picasso:2.5.2

Well, i think its a cache problem, or something like this

**The error is**

````
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method with(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; in class Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.picasso.Picasso' appears in /data/app/app.package.here/base.apk:classes3.dex)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.IconRenderer.renderIconFromResource(IconRenderer.java:64)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.IconRenderer.render(IconRenderer.java:33)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.IconRenderer.render(IconRenderer.java:18)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.view.Renderer.render(Renderer.java:35)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.HeaderRenderer.render(HeaderRenderer.java:42)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.HeaderRenderer.render(HeaderRenderer.java:18)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.view.Renderer.render(Renderer.java:35)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.PaymentResultRenderer.render(PaymentResultRenderer.java:24)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.components.PaymentResultRenderer.render(PaymentResultRenderer.java:10)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.view.Renderer.render(Renderer.java:35)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.view.ComponentManager.render(ComponentManager.java:30)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.view.ComponentManager.onProps(ComponentManager.java:64)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.PaymentResultPropsMutator.notifyPropsChanged(PaymentResultPropsMutator.java:60)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.PaymentResultPresenter.checkGetInstructions(PaymentResultPresenter.java:99)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.PaymentResultPresenter.onValidStart(PaymentResultPresenter.java:72)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.PaymentResultPresenter.initialize(PaymentResultPresenter.java:52)
        at com.mercadopago.android.px.internal.features.paymentresult.PaymentResultActivity.onResume(PaymentResultActivity.java:150)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

Well, i resolved this using in the **app.gradle**

Code found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404372/6046390

```
android {
    ...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    }
}
```