# Error with adding dependencies to my build.gradle in android studio (Conflict with dependency)

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle, google-sheets-api

I am new to android studio and am trying to add Google sheets api v4. [On their website](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android) it says to add some dependencies to my build.gradle file.
Here is what my gradle currently looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The error occurs when I try to add the following lines

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev483-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

When I try to sync my Gradle I instead get this error:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

Any help fixing this would be appreciated as I am pretty new to android studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347326/errorconflict-with-dependency-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` (in app folder) add the following inside `android{}` body

```
android {

   ....

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357786/8405762