# Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, dex, android-studio-3.0

I have Android Studio Beta. I created a new project with compile my old modules but when I tried launching the app it did not launch with the message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

But I don't know how to solve this error. I googled this for hours but with no success.

My project gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "parad0x.sk.onlyforyou"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.7
        sourceCompatibility 1.7
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile project(path: ':loginregisterview')


}
```

And my module gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':parser')

}
```

My second module:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

    //   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0'
 //   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0'
 //   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

____________finding_________

When I did not import the second module (parser) the app did not crash on dex but when the module was not imported app did not work. :D :D

Comment: If anyone is getting the same issue in Android Studio 3.0 Stable version, I would strongly recommend you to review the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949761/unable-to-merge-dex-android-studio-3-0/46971548#46971548 and see if it can help you.

Comment: I had the same problem and I followed every method which is mentioned on this page but didn't help me out so I go to the gradle and hold cursor on each library to check their new version is available or not. those who have new version so I updated, sync gradle and run. it worked.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

I had the same problem when I update from `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0`. This solved it for me:

1. clean
2. rebuild

Comment: You only delay the real problem with that solution. probably ver 11.4.0 contains less methods. See my answer below. you will got this error in the next dependence you'll add I guess

Comment: This solves my issue, where `multiDexEnabled true` alone did not

Comment: same isse with com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0 ... this is not a valid solution

Comment: This solution worked for me when I had a compatibility problem using google analytics libraries. In AS view the android project navigator pane as "Project", you should see "External Libraries", if you expand the external libraries, you'll see all the jars and modules used to compile the project. It should help you identify incompatible module combinations.

Comment: If above code is not work in case of "compileSdkVersion 26", try this.. go to - build.gradle(Module:app) - add " multiDexEnabled true " in defaultConfig category and last step Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Instant Run and try to Enable/Disable

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.0.

Answer (score 359):

I tried all the above and none of them helps. finally, I find this work for me:

**app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem was that most answers are not accounting for including JAR files from other sources that you cannot rebuild. multiDex seems to allow the otherwise incompatible code to be combined.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but in addition, I had to explicitly enable multidex for API <= 21  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: DEspite being more relevant than the accepted answer I still get "Unable to merge dex" message

Comment: Also needed to add `multiDexEnabled true` for all modules

Comment: Didn't work for me. With this change I got different error:  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

Comment: Yes for 5 hours i was dwelling with totally different answers. But somehow I realized it was Multidex issue and landed here. I was true. Thanks man

Answer (score 61):

## Pay attention to Warnings!

Sometimes you only need to eliminate **warnings** and the **error** will be disappeared automatically. See below special case:

---

I had these two dependencies in my module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

and Studio **had warned** (*in addition to dex merging problem*):

> All `com.android.support` libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions `27.0.2`, `21.0.3`. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2` and `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3`

**So I explicitly determined the version of `com.android.support:support-v4`** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/5318303) for details) **and both problems** (the warning and the one related to dex merging) ***solved***:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'  // Added this line (according to above warning message)
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

---

<sup>*See below comments for other similar situations.*</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue for me. It was originally caused by adding eu.inloop:androidviewmodel:1.3.4

Comment: Exactly, I just wish the error could have been more precise

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same issue. I was using v26, updated to sdk 27 and solved the problem.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. My builds stopped working after adding one library (airbnb/epoxy) which had a dependency to `support:design:26.1.0`, and I didn't have that dependency yet. My others support libraries version was 27.1.0. After adding `support:design` dependency with `27.1.0` version, my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 37):

In my case, Unfortunately, neither Michel's nor Suragch's solutions worked for me.

So I solved this issue by doing the following:

In **gradle:3.0** the **compile** configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by **implementation** or **api**. For more information you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/3983054) You can read the official docs at [Gradle Build Tool](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

> The compile  configuration still exists but should not be used as it will not offer  the guarantees that the api and implementation
>   configurations provide.

it's better to use **implementation** or **api** rather **compile**

just replace **compile** with **implementation**, **debugCompile** with **debugImplementation**, **testCompile** with **testImplementation** and **androidtestcompile** with **androidTestImplementation**

For example: Instead of this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

use like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

After that

- Delete the .gradle folder inside your project  ( Note that, in order to see .gradle, you need to switch to the "Project" view in the navigator on the top left )
- Delete all the **build folders** and the gradle cache.
- From the Build menu, press the **Clean Project** button.
- After task completed, press the **Rebuild Project** button from the Build menu.

Hope it will helps !

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was change compile to implementation and it built successfully, didn't have to complete the other steps. The build started failing after I updated the Facebook SDK

Comment: Worked for me - insights into why?

Comment: The folder to delete should be `.gradle` and not `./gradle`

Comment: Also `testImplementation` instead of `testCompile`.

Comment: I already mentioned it in my answer. anyways thanks for saying

Comment: Why would `implementation` work and `compile` won't? They should have made it backward compatible. Anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: The only answer that actually worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the "gradle cache"?

Comment: Thanks, It is the coolest answer. It should be on top of the search. Worked for me.

Answer (score 32):

1. Delete the `.gradle` directory.
2. Run your app again.

**Notes**

- The `.gradle` directory is in your project's root folder. (You may have to show hidden files first.)
- I have to do this every time I update a dependency module using Android 3.0. (More recent releases of Android Studio 3 seem to have resolved the problem.)

Comment: this helped me when I also did a Invalidate Cache and restart

Comment: I was in disbelief when this fixed my issue.. i had tried updating everything, removing all compile keywords, updating a few of the suspect ilb versions.. when i finally did this, it worked..

Answer (score 26):

Deleting `.gradle` as suggested by Suragch wasn't enough for me. Additionally, I had to perform a `Build > Clean Project`.

Note that, in order to see `.gradle`, you need to switch to the "Project" view in the navigator on the top left:

[image: Switch to project view]

Answer (score 23):

I tried every other solution, but no one worked for me. At the end, i solved it by using same dependency version by editing `build.gradle`. I think this problem occurres when adding a library into gradle which uses different dependency version of support or google libraries.

Add following code to your build gradle file. Then `clean` and `rebuild` project.

> ps: that was old solution for me so you should use updated version of
>   following libraries.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.1.0'
        }
    } else if (requested.group == "com.google.android.gms") {
        details.useVersion '11.8.0'
        } else if (requested.group == "com.google.firebase") {
            details.useVersion '11.8.0'
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: tried all other solutions, in the end only this helped :/

Comment: @Ali Gurelli Thank you so much i tried many solutions but only this work  only.

Comment: Thanx But For me I use Version
                details.useVersion '15.0.0'

Comment: Thanks for solution. Same issue happened to me . google tap and pay was 10.0.0 and rest all libs are on latest version

Comment: Worked Smoothly Thanks

Comment: I need to tell, you saved my morning!

Answer (score 17):

if(1. Try to clean and rebuild work ) then good

else if (2. Try to remove gradle work ) then good

else-> 3. Try to add in grade.properties

```
android.enableD8 = false
```

> Edit 2021: This 3rd option is deprecated now, use the other options

else-> 4. Add `multiDexEnabled` true to your build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
      ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
     ...
    }
}
```

and add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}
```

It may the first one works for u and so on but it really depends on the nature of your problem for me for example

I got the error once I have added this library

```
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
```

and later I discovered that I have to check that and I have to add the same version of the support libraries. So I have to try another version

```
compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
```

and it fixes the problem. So pay attention for that.

Comment: The most useful way for this problem. One I want to mention here is that, you can use 'gradlew app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug --stacktrace' cmd for more details. I save me, found I have to enable multidex. Hope helpful.

Comment: @DINA, `android.enableD8 = false` is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

In my case issue was because of the room library:

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Changing it to:

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
```

worked.

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me a lot!

Comment: So glad to find this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the above solutions:

Make sure that you don't have duplicate dependencies pointing to
different versions of them, in multiple places (or even in the same file).

Comment: I think this should be first check before adding multiDexEnabled true, and trying other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Hi I have same issue tried almost everything. So, finally i resolved after 6 hour long struggle by debugging everything line by line.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

**Google-services 3.0** Doesn't support firebase with Studio 3.0 with playServiceVersion: 11.6.0 or less.

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.ext.playServiceVersion"
implementation "com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:$rootProject.ext.jobdispatcherVersion"
```

**Solution :**

I have change ***google services*** to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

And it support firebase services.

Hopefully somebody save his/her time.

Comment: I have the same issue I was using playServiceVersion as 11.4.0  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0"  change it to implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2" fixed my issue . So please verify the version dependency for different lib

Answer (score 9):

1. Enable

   defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
2. If step 1 doesn't work then

   Go to project structure and find out the external library which is using a
   different version. Double click on it and delete its jar file. Close the project and open again android studio will rebuild the project.
   The problem should be gone.

Comment: +1 - I had the support lib, rxjava and a 3rd party dependency (13k lines).  My eyes nearly popped out when I saw the method count.

Answer (score 6):

One of the possibilities is: **the presence of the same library but with different versions in the dependencies**.

I had this problem with the following lines in gradle file:

- `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
- `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`

The gson library was in my libs directory but with a previous version.
I deleted the `gson-2.3.1.jar` from the libs directory and everything is back to normal.

Comment: removing `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` fixed for me too.. thanks (y)

Answer (score 5):

If this error appeared for you after including kotlin support, and none of the other solutions work, try changing the kotlin dependency of app module's `build.gradle` to:

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version") {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

This works for me on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531584/6346531) answer for further explanation.

Comment: Yep, it seems that Kotlin introduction could break the build if the annotations are not excluded.

Comment: Thanks. This was the fix for me. I struggle 3 days to identify my problem.

Comment: Try upgrading to Kotlin plugin version 1.2.30 instead (just released). Now Instant Run can be enabled again too!

Answer (score 5):

[With Android Studio 3.0 stable build](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#3-0-0) Below steps worked for me:

1. Got to SdkManager-->Android Sdk --> Sdk Tools and Update Google play services to latest version to 46.
2. Clean project and rebuild project.

Answer (score 5):

[ UNABLE TO MERGE DEX SOLVED ]
After hours of stack overflowing 
I resolved the " UNABLE TO MERGE DEX ERROR "

1. Update all the com.android.support lines in your gradle to v27.1.0

Cause - Android has updated it support libraries to v27.1.0, so you have to change all the android support lines in your gradle file to 27.1.0 from 26.1.0

2. Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

   allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
   }
   }

Cause :- Android cannot  update the support libraries in the SDK manager and now it uses maven.google.com to update , so you have to include this to use 27.1.0 support libraries

**After Change Version:**
 1. Clean Project
 2. Rebuild Project

Answer (score 4):

add commands below:

```
android {
...

    dexOptions {

        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Installing Google play services (latest version) + including

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
}
```

in build.gradle solved the issue for me, make sure to clean and rebuild project!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Chris-Jr. If you are using Firebase to embed your AdMob ads (or even if you are not) the play-services-analytics includes the play-services-ads even though you don't add that as a dependency.  Google have obviously made a mistake in their 11.4.0 roll-out as the analytics is including version 10.0.1 of ads, not 11.4.0 (the mouse over hint in the gradle shows this).

I manually added *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'* at the top which worked, but only after I disabled Instant Run: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/530047

So its either regress to 10.0.1 or add the ads and disable Instant Run.
That's what I found if it helps any.

Comment: Did OP mention Play Services?

Comment: The approved answer did. If this issue is surfacing without that scenario then I don't know!

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was  **gson-2.8.1.jar** which I have added to **libs** folder of the project. But the reference was already there by SDK.
So it was not necesary to add **gson-2.8.1.jar** to libs folder.

When I **took it out th  gson-2.8.1.jar** project compiles without this wiered error.

So try to revise **libs** folder and **dependencies**.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and found the real reason for my case.
Previously, I also tried all the previous answers again, but it did not solve the problem.
I have two module in my wear app project, and the build.gradle as follows：

wear module's build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':common')
implementation files('libs/farmer-motion-1.0.jar')
```

common module's build.gradle:

```
implementation files('libs/farmer-motion-1.0.jar')
```

Before upgrade to gradle 3.x, 'implementation' are all 'compile'.

I run gradlew with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace, you can just click this on gradle console window when this problem arises. And found that dependency to the jar package repeated:

```
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/farmer/motion/common/data/pojo/SportSummary$2;
```

Class SportSummary in the farmer-motion-1.0.jar package, after read the [official migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations), i changed my build.gradle to follows:

wear module's build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':common')
// delete dependency implementation files('libs/farmer-motion-1.0.jar')
```

common module的build.gradle:

```
api files('libs/farmer-motion-1.0.jar') // change implementation to api
```

Now wear module will has the dependency of farmer-motion-1.0.jar export by common module. 
If there **has no dependency on jar package during runtime**, '**implementation**' dependency of jar package **can also be change to 'compileOnly'**.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem.

I was able to solve by changing `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to latest version.

Answer (score 2):

For our project, we accidentally added same jar two times with different name. Removing one of them solved the issue.

Comment: This solved my issue.  I was building an internal android library project and under its `libs` folder, I had two jar files, one of which is just a backup of the other one but with a different filename.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be your problem, but I got this error when I accidentally included two identical (but differently named) libraries in the dependencies{} section of the project.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was updating the firebase messaging in **app\build.gradle:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible root causes: duplicate transient dependencies that weren't properly handled by Android Studio import of multi-module projects. Check your list and remove them. For me, the fix was literally this:

```
--- a/project/module/build.gradle
+++ b/project/module/build.gradle
@@ -21,5 +21,4 @@ android {
 dependencies {
     implementation project(':upstream-dependency-project')
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
-    implementation files('libs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find out the reason of this problem for my project. ***I was added one dependency twice in build.gradle***. One time by adding dependency and one  time again by adding jar dependency:

**compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'

...

implementation files('../achartengine-1.2.0.jar')**

after remove the first line problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

In case the top answers haven't worked for you, your issue may be that you have multiple dependencies that depend on the same library.

Here are some debugging tips. In this sample code,  `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0` is the offending library.

**Always clean and rebuild every time you modify to check your solution!**

1. Build with the `--stacktrace` flag on for more detail. It will complain about a class, Google that class to find the library. [Here's how you can set up Android studio to always run gradle with the `--stacktrace` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project/21674403#21674403).
2. Take a glance at the Gradle Console in Android Studio `View > Tool Windows > Gradle Console` after a build
3. Check for repeated dependences by running `./gradlew -q app:dependencies`. You can re-run this each time you modify the your build.gradle.
4. In build.gradle,

   ```
   android {
           ...
           configurations.all {
               resolutionStrategy {
                   // Force a particular version of the library 
                   // across all dependencies that have that dependency
                   force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
               }
           }
   }
   ```
5. In build.gradle,

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.6.0') {
           // Exclude the library for this particular import
           exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
       }
   }
   ```
6. In build.gradle,

   ```
   android {
       ...
       configurations.all {
           resolutionStrategy {
               // Completely exclude the library. Works for transitive
               // dependencies.
               exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. If some of your dependencies are in jar files, open up the jar files and see if there are any conflicting class names. If they are, you will probably have to re-build the jars with new class names or look into [shading](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

Some more background reading:

- [Android - Understanding and dominating gradle dependencies](https://www.devsbedevin.com/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/)
- [Gradle Documentation: Dependency Management for Java Projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)
- [Gradle Documentation: ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)
- StackOverflow: [Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347326/errorconflict-with-dependency-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305/37357786#37357786)
- StackOverflow: [How do I exclude all instances of a transitive dependency when using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle)
- [Google search StackOverflow for all related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple%20dex%20files%20site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2rseutqnZAhUh2oMKHaYZAnUQrQIINSgEMAA&biw=1094&bih=983)

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I also had the same problem but I realized that solve my problem at that moment but in the future updates, things might actually change.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a library makes this problem, library was successfully added to project but when i run my app it shows me this error. So if this happens to you too, you can go to github and check issues or raise new issue. If you do not find any solution regarding the library i suggest you to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
I just enabled `Instant Run`(It was disabled) then my project worked.
You can find it in-

```
File->Settings-> Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run
```

In Android studio 3.5 *Instant Run* have been removed.
Please see [here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57616477)

Comment: There is no Instant Run in the path called "Build, Execution, Deployment" your answer has no meaning.

Comment: @Bay in Android studio 3.5 Instant Run  is not available.My answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither Michel's nor Suragch's solutions worked for me.

What I eventually had to do was simply rollback my `com.google.firebase:firebase-database` to version 10.0.1, since 11.4.0 was causing a dependency inconsistency warning in my app gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I import one 'android_support' lib twice ,so I delete one under 'libs' directory and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

try like this, it works for me.

In app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....

    compile project(':grow-notification')

    /** Firebase Start **/
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    /** Firebase End **/
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

while in module grow-notification/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....

    /** Firebase Start **/
    provided 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    provided 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    /** Firebase End **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I implemented the same library twice in my build.gradle file. Removing the duplicate entry worked for me. And did not even  needed to clean, rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution worked for me:

1. Don't compile/implement two versions of same dependencies.
2. Don't use .jar file in **libs** folder of your project, if you are compiling it directly from gradle. Above point applies here too.

Then **Clean** and **Rebuild** project.

Comment: How to know it? `Don't compile/implement two versions of same dependencies.`

Comment: `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'` with different version `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'` or a `.jar` file in libs with `firebase-messaging**-**12.3.2.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by performing a clean and then building the project from Android Studio 3.0  menu:

1. build -> clean project
2. build-> rebuild project

Comment: It does not help

Answer (score 0):

For most of cases this works.
It works for me .
Good Luck if it works for you too.

Step 1:In build.gradle (Module:app)
add this:
          defaultConfig{
             multiDexEnabled true
           }

Step 2: do this: Build=> Clean Project

Step 3: do this: Build=> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

```
./gradlew :app:assembleStubLiveDebug -debug -stacktrace
```

Or similar (get the task name (`:app:assembleStubLiveDebug`) from Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem when you have added two version of the same library..either in the dependency or in the library....It my case and almost every time this fixes the issue..

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have more then two modules and sdks, I try all suggestion or answer listed above like

- add multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig
- Clean and Rebuild project
- replacing compile with implementing
- update all dependencies

All these work temporarily but when I open project structure(cntrl + altr + shift+ s) i found, In my Project Property nothing will selected like-
 - compile SDK version, build sdk version
 - In flavors same

I update all these and perform clean and rebuild project and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            }
    }

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

**build clean and build Rebuild**

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading some dependency I found solutions. We should use latest play service version. In **build.gradle[app]** dependency.

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

In **build.gradle[project]**, we should use latest Google plug-in.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

I am also sharing below code for better understanding.

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***.user"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 26
        versionName "1.0.20"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        aaptOptions {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that 2 of the jars that I included in the project had the same classes in them.

For 1 of these jars I needed to exclude the classes:

```
jar {
    exclude('com/files/to/exclude/**')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was importing the dependency:

*implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'*

and I was not using it, it started working when I deleted it cleaned project and recomplied. Of course I also did what the people above did which was:

- Changing complie to implementation throughout the whole app.grade
- Changing testcomplie to testimplementation throughout the whole app.grade
- Make sure I have multidexenabled true
- Update compileSdk to 26
- Deleted .gradle file (found in project), clean project and recompile

and finally...

- **Deleted** implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0' (Since I was not using it in my code)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a duplicated dependency (possibly nested in another dependency). Use "gradlew app:dependencies" in the command-line to verify all of your dependencies.

After removing duplicates, the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I spend more than 3 hours reading and testing all the responses.
Finally the problem was the library "joda time",

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963117/3994630) I found the problem, **run the gradle console with full stack trace** and read the error detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note: update your all support library to 27.1.0 like above and remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

check dependencies version if they are not same then make it same it will solve your problem

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile` in **build.gradle**. Change it to `debugImplementation` and `releaseImplementation`. This was how I have solved it, gradle should pass through this successfully marked instructions as deprecated, but suddenly it stucked exactly on this two.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all same source library have same version number. In my case I was using different google api versions. I was using **11.6.0** for all google libraries but **10.4.0** for google place api. After updating google place api to **11.6.0**, problem fixed.

Please note that my multidex is also enabled for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Change you buildToolsVersion to some other version and sync, change it back and sync again. It will work again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebsae in your plugin, this issue will come due to play services version issue, try this 
    `cordov

```js
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0
    cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
    cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
    cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0
    cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1
    cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0
    cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0
```

Change your project.properties like this, then this issue will be resolved
[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me-

Add code at last in platforms\android\build.gradle

```
configurations.all { 
 resolutionStrategy{
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    }

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
       if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
      details.useVersion '26.0.0'
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your **app/build.gradle**. It will work

**implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'**

Answer (score 0):

Just add below in build.gradle,

defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't been shared here yet so hopefully it can help someone.

Following this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) solved the same issue for me.

To begin, I'll note that I did not have to set multiDexEnabled to true.

First I set dependencies in my pubspec.yaml to

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```

and ran `flutter packages get` in my IDE's terminal.

Also I had to change the minimum target SDK version:

1. Open android/app/build.gradle, then find the line that says
   minSdkVersion 16.
2. Change that line to minSdkVersion 21.
3. Save the file.

This alone may fix your problem; however I had to also do the following because some of my dependency versions were mismatched.

I had to open `android/app/build.gradle`, then add the following line as the last line in the file:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Next, I had to open `android/build.gradle`, then inside the buildscript tag, add a new dependency:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       // ...
   }

   dependencies {
       // ...
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'   // new
   }
}
```

After this my app finally ran on the android emulator.

The [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6) has a more complete walkthrough if you get stuck.

Also, to note, I did not have to set multiDexEnabled to true.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following works

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
```

In my `app` module. The problem was they firebase-analytics latest library, it is not working properly with the other latest libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go `Unity >> Edit Project settings>>player`, look for `Minify` section and then choose the `Proguard` option

Answer (score 0):

Along with **Unable to merge dex** I had an error **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** when building a project.

In the **gradle.properties** file I had this commented line:

```
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Uncommenting this line and increasing the heap memory to **3g** solved the problem:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score -1):

Tried all of them before focusing on dependencies.

The below where killers:

```
//implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'
//implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.1'
```

Now is working as intended.

Comment: This should probably be a comment to the answer from @Mansour The duplicate references will make it fail. This response on its own does not offer new insight on this issue. OP has already accepted an answer on this thread so make sure your answer explains why it is different to the others and is of a similar high quality with links to reference material and in-depth explanation. Some of the other answers to this question are really good examples of well structured and referenced posts.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using

```
compile ("org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.1")
```

you should change it to

```
compile ("org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.1"){
    exclude group:'org.apache.oltu.oauth2' , module: 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common'
}
```

As the client lib already contains the common lib it creates a duplicate class entry which gives an error:

> Unable to merge dex