# "Unable to merge dex" error when useing Room + Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

> I'm not a native English user. Please excuse my spelling and grammar error.

I try to implement Android architecture Room database interface with Kotlin. After introducing Room into my project, the app occurs build error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I run gradlew in terminal and get the following error messages:

```
// from gradlew
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMonoDex(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:178)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:119)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:121)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.lambda$mergeMonoDex$0(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/persistence/room/SharedSQLiteStatement;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
        ... 1 more
```

I've tried the solutions in this question :[Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex) . They doesn't work for me.

---

The build.gradle file and Room database files are list as follow:

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    // version code
    def verMajor = 0
    def verMinor = 0
    def verPatch = 1
    def verHotfix = ''

    // compile wtih sdk 26 (Android - O)
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tomazwang.project.kotlinandroid"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode verMajor * 10000 + verMinor * 100 + verPatch
        versionName "$verMajor.$verMinor.$verPatch$verHotfix"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // support library
    String supportVersion = '26.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1"

    // Anko
    String anko_version = '0.10.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"

    // RxJava
    String rxJavaVersion = '2.1.4'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"

    String rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"

    // Android architecture
    String anArchVersion = '1.0.0-alpha9-1'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$anArchVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$anArchVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$anArchVersion"

    // Stetho
    String stethoVersion = '1.5.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:$stethoVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

```
//  AppDatabase.kt
@Database(
        entities = arrayOf(Todo::class),
        version = DbContract.VERSION
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun todoDao(): TodoDao

    companion object {
        fun createInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase
                = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java).build()

        fun createPersistentDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase
                = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, DbContract.DB_NAME).build()
    }
}
```

```java
// TodoDao.kt
@Dao
abstract class TodoDao {

    fun createTodo(name: String, description: String = "") {
        insertOrUpdate(Todo(
                id = 0,
                name = name,
                position = lastPosition() + 1,
                description = description
        ))
    }

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract fun insertOrUpdate(todo: Todo)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${TableTodo.TABLE_NAME} WHERE ${TableTodo.COL_ID} = :id")
    abstract fun getTodo(id: Long): Maybe<Todo>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${TableTodo.TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY ${TableTodo.COL_POSITION}")
    abstract fun getTodos(): Flowable<List<Todo>>
}
```

```
// Todo.kt
@Entity(
        tableName = TableTodo.TABLE_NAME
)
data class Todo(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = TableTodo.COL_ID) val id: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = TableTodo.COL_NAME) val name: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = TableTodo.COL_POSITION) val position: Long = 0,
        @ColumnInfo(name = TableTodo.COL_DESCRIPTION) val description: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = TableTodo.COL_CHECKED) val checked:Boolean = false
)
```

Comment: Which version of Kotlin do you have defined in `kotlin_version`? I've been seeing a similar error after updating to 1.1.50/51 combined with the Android extensions. Downgrading to 1.1.4-3 fixed it. Your error does appear to be two libraries importing Room, though. Check that with `./gradlew dependencies`

Comment: @AdamS The error happens when I use version 1.1.4. Currently, I'm using the latest 1.1.51 version and the problem solved. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem source:

```
Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/persistence/room/SharedSQLiteStatement;
```

Recheck dependencies, probably you have `Room` included more than one time.

Comment: After checking dependencies, use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`, and clean and re-build my project. It finally works! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
String anArchVersion = '1.0.0-alpha9-1'
```

with:

```
String anArchVersion = '1.0.0-rc1'
```

Answer (score 1):

As @TomazWang said, use kapt instead of annotationProcessor while declaring dependencies in build.gradle file, and clean and re-build my project. It solved my issue. Thanks Tomaz.

```
dependencies {
  // Dagger 2
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
  kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1';
```

to this:

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0';
```