# Error Generating APK After Updating Android Studio to stable release 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated to stable version of android studio 3.0. Earlier, everything was fine. But now I am getting an error while building my app apk file. Here are the screenshots of error and my Gradle File. I tried deleting .gradle folder from my project. Invalidating the caches and restarting the android Studio. I also cleaned my project and rebuilt it… But the error remained… Please help…[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG9aE.png)

Comment: have you tried clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Please see this question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex

Comment: obviously you have two support libraries with different versions

Comment: @Selvin which two libraries??

Comment: obiously newest 26 and 26 alpha

Answer (score 0):

try with disabling aapt2 by putting `android.enableAapt2=false` in gradle.properties

Comment: Tried it but didn't worked... Error is showing again

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: which buildToolsversion you are using?

Comment: My Build tool Version is 3.0.0

Comment: No sorry... its 26.0.2

Comment: Could you update the compile dependencies to implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' version should be 26.1.0.Also please check whether each compile dependencies have same android dependencies. This can be done by using Gradle(right corner of android studio)->go to your module->tasks->android->android dependencies

Comment: Still showing the same error. i updated the version... Updated the 'compile' to 'implementation'

Comment: Now the error i gone after removing google play services dependency... Thank you soo much ma'am.. :)