# Unable to Merge Dex Android Studio 3.0 after update

Tags: java, android

updated my project to gradle 3 and generated this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

in another questions says "libraries having transitive dependency " but i don't find the library with this transitive dependency

in gradle 2.3 don't show this error

build.gradle app
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.my"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':dd-plist')
    compile project(':Emojicon')
    compile project(':CameraModule')
    compile project(':ScapeUtils')
    compile project(':circleimageview')
    compile project(':FFMPG')
    compile project(':PdfViewer')
    compile project(':LibLinphone')
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.ornolfr:rating-view:0.1.1@aar'
    compile 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'   
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex

Comment: i update play services & firebase but  the error was not solved

Comment: okay then, add multiDex support in your app

Comment: I think you should delete build folder and try again to build.

Answer (score 0):

I am battling also with this or similar problem. I have set to use the old gradle version manually. From File/Project structure/projet I have put gradle version 3.4.1 and plugin version 2.3.3
I have also added multiDexEnabled true in app/build.gradle inside defaultConfig Hth