# java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I am using MVVM design pattern for my android application.

When I am adding `implementation android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$project.lifecycle" kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$project.lifecycle"`

I am getting below error

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:

I read on multiple threads [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex) to fix it but it didn't work for me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // set build config here for debug builds
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://52.15.45.102\"")
        }
        release {
            // set build config here for release builds
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://52.15.45.102\"")
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

project.ext {
    daggerVersion = "2.11"
    anko_version = '0.10.1'
    roomDatabase = '1.0.0-alpha3'
    lifecycle = '1.0.0-alpha3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$project.anko_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.0"

    // Dagger core
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$project.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$project.daggerVersion"

    // Dagger Android
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$project.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$project.daggerVersion"
    // if you are not using support library, include this instead
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$project.daggerVersion"


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'

    // Database
    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$project.roomDatabase"
    //kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$project.roomDatabase"

    // Viewmodel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$project.lifecycle"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$project.lifecycle"

    // new version 1.5.2 has some multi dex issue
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'

    // Databinding
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"

    // Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2', {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version") {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }

}
```

Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    ext.gradle_version = '3.0.0-beta7'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**AppPartnerApplication.kt**

```
class AppPartnerApplication : Application(), AnkoLogger, HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return activityInjector
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)
    }

    override protected fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
$ gradlew build

> Configure project :app
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\android-ndk-r15.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-22-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-22')
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\williams\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
app: 'androidProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha01'.

> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
w:

w: D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\src\main\java\com\appandroid\android\data\remote\CallbackWrapper.kt: (45, 39): No cast needed
w: D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\src\main\java\com\appandroid\android\login\LoginViewModel.kt: (36, 15): Parameter 'view' is never used

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
D8 is used to build dex.

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
D8 is used to merge dex.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar

        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:225)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor488.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar

        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:96)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:82)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:35)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:61)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$44(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
        at java.util.Map.merge(Map.java:1175)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:22)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:114)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:93)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:175)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:149)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:68)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:80)
        ... 57 more



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52, D:\android\apppartnerandroid\appandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53....

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
25 actionable tasks: 25 executed
```

Comment: What's your *gradle.properties* version ?

Comment: I added in the question @Ibrahim

Comment: I mean gradle.properties wrapper some thing like `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-xx-all.zip`

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: can you just try with version `4.3`?

Comment: ok lemme try it with 4.3

Comment: I am getting same error `Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives`

Comment: @Williams I am having the same issue, did you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if you can update your android architecture components version then see how it goes.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have been stuck with this problem for hours. I'm curious how did you find out that this was the issue?

Comment: probably by trying different hit and trials :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that I commented out apache.commons to solve it in my case.  squareup must be implementing commons, so I don't need to.  Sure do like retrofit and picasso.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:2.7.4+22'
implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:2.7.4+22'

//implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
```