# Getting dex merge issue when build the gradle in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I unable to build the **`gradle`** and getting error.I'm using android studio 3.0 stable version

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Detail:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task   
':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Studio Projects\SampleMVP 
\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't   read [D:\Studio Projects\SampleMVP\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\13.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [13.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$1.class]))
Information:BUILD FAILED in 4m 6s
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**My `app gradle`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ocs.com.samplemvp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}


compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I tried to many time clean and rebuild but not working

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Rebuild your project if you can't from android studio menu Invalidate caches/ restrat...

**2.** Clean your project then rebuild it.

**3.** Delete `/build` directory in `/project` directory and delete `/build` directory from `/project/app/` directory , then remake the project.

**5.** From android studio menu Invalidate caches/ restrat... 
**4.** If you already installed the application uninstall it.

[Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex) can help you

Comment: My issue is fixed when I downgrade support lib version **26.1.0** from  **27.0.0** and thanks all

Comment: have you done these steps ?

Comment: yes after downgrade I followed it

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Rebuild your project

**2.** Clean your project then rebuild it.

**3.** Delete `/build` directory in `/project` directory and delete `/build` directory from `/project/app/` directory , then remake the project.

**4.** If you already installed the application uninstall it.

Comment: I unable to rebuild the app