# Error:(30, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I get this error. I'm pretty confused because i check everything in sdk manager and it's all updated (i think so).

> Error:(30, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

Is there something wrong with my code in build.grandle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

or is something missing...?

Comment: which gradle version your using? if 3.0.0 follow like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex/47304057#47304057

Comment: Might want to read this again... `NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here;`... @KingofMasses That error is very different

Answer (score 3):

You **can't use** the `compile()` DSL in the **top level file**.

Delete this block:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

and add the dependency in the `dependencies` block inside the `app/build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "compile" when using Gradle build tools 3.0.0.

"compile" has been replaced with "implementation".

And you can't add dependencies in the project build.gradle file.
You have to add dependencies in the module build.gradle file.

So in the build.gradle file in the "app" directory, add these lines:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

The "dependencies" block might already be there, if so, just add the contents to the original block.