# How to fix android studio crashing?

Tags: android-studio

I am working in Android Studio and I have this error:

> ERROR: Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0] on object of
>   type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

When I open my project in Android Studio the program suddenly closes.

My code:

```
package com.example.block07;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.graphics.Color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.view.View;

import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    NumberPicker np;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get the widgets reference from XML layout
          final TextView tv;
         tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

         final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);

         final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

AdjustBridge.registerAndGetInstance(getApplication(), webview)

                //Set TextView text color
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF2C834F"));

                //Initializing a new string array with elements
                final String[] values = {"Tunisia", "France", "Espagne", 
"Chine", "Russie"};

                //Populate NumberPicker values from String array values
                //Set the minimum value of NumberPicker
                np.setMinValue(0); //from array first value
                //Specify the maximum value/number of NumberPicker
                np.setMaxValue(values.length - 1); //to array last value

                //Specify the NumberPicker data source as array elements
                np.setDisplayedValues(values);

                //Gets whether the selector wheel wraps when reaching the 
min/max value.
                np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

                //Set a value change listener for NumberPicker
                np.setOnValueChangedListener(new 
NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                    private View v;

                    @Override
                    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int 
oldVal, int newVal) {
                        //Display the newly selected value from picker
                        tv.setText("Selected value : " + values[newVal]);
                    }

                    public void navigate(View v) {
try{ 
                        int choice = np.getValue();
                        if (choice == 0)

webView.loadUrl("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunisie");
                        else if (choice == 1)

webView.loadUrl("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/France");
                         else if (choice == 2)

webView.loadUrl("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espagne");
                        else if (choice == 3)

webView.loadUrl("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chine");
                         else if (choice == 4)

webView.loadUrl("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russie");
                    }
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe similar, you can try this. If don't work then please share your gradle file.

[Error:(30, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391294/error30-0-could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments)