# Android application on Gradle: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, twilio

I have an error with my app in Android studio:

```
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I use Gradle and Kotlin.

```
Android Studio 3.0.1.  
Windows 10 Pro 64.
```

I have research this theme on SO and I have tried some solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex), like that:

1. Clean and rebuild project. No changes.
2. Change 'compile' in gradle to 'implementation'. No changes.
3. Delete `.gradle` and `build` directories. No changes.
4. Add `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig` in gradle. In this case, I have another error:

   ```
    Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. 
    > java.io.IOException: Can't write [G:\work\myapp\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] 
     (Can't read [C:\Users\Public\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-27.0.2.aar\e1c9881d763269b67bf59dc03d19c305\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
     (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker$PermissionResult.class]))
   ```

My **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
       applicationId "myapp"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 27
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    staging {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix ".sta"
    }
    preproduction {
        applicationIdSuffix ".pre"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.basecamp:turbolinks:1.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // The Client SDK resides on jCenter
    implementation 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.21'
}
```

My **AndroidManifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tunnll.passenger">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" 
                           android:exported="false" android:stopWithTask="true"/>   
</application>
```

What am I missing?

**UPD**
It seems I found out the point after that the problem has appeared. It was after adding Twilio configuration. I used this manual: [Twilio and Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android)

This is all changes that have been done:

1. Add to `build.gradle`:

   ```
     implementation 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.21'
   ```
2. Add to `AndroidManifest`:

   ```
     <service android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" 
                  android:exported="false" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
   ```
3. Add to `proguard-rules.pro`

   ```
     # Twilio Client
     -keep class com.twilio.** { *; }

     # Apache HttpClient
     -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
   ```

That's all. Before this changes I didn't have this error

Comment: do you have anything under libs folder?

Comment: Invalidate caches/restart?

Comment: @global_warming, no, it seems I don't have the libs directory in the project structure

Comment: @AswinPAshok, tried restart, no result :(

Comment: I think you have conflicting dependencies. You have included `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2` in your Gradle, but turbolinks library is [compiled with  support library `25.1.1`](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android/blob/master/turbolinks/build.gradle). So try compiling without turbolink library. Still not sure it is the reason for your problem. Read [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/avoiding-conflicts-in-android-gradle-dependencies-28e4200ca235) to avoid dependancy conflicts

Comment: @AswinPAshok it seems I found the point when the problem has appeared, and it's not turbolinks configuring

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `build.gradle` in app Module if you want to read an `.aar` file
for your libs dir:

```
repositories{
      flatDir{
              dirs 'libs'
       }
 }

dependencies {
   compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
}
```

But it seems that your problem is multidex(means that you have more than 65K methods in your project so use this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

and if your minSdk < 20 then use this as well:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Well, I have added `multiDexEnabled true` and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`, but it doesn't help, I see the first error: `Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

Comment: But I'm sorry, I didn't understand about .aar files, it seems I don't have any .aar files in the project structure

Comment: ok do this. Go to the home directory "C:\Users\your user\.gradle\ and delete the entire cache folder. The go to the project folder and delete the .gradle folder. Then open Android Studio and try to sync

Comment: I did it all, Android Studio had successful sync, but when I run the project I see the same error

Comment: It seems I found the point when this problem has appeared. I have edited the post