# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: java, android

Here is dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'io.nlopez.smartlocation', name: 'library', version: '3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.jota.autocompletelocation:autocomplete-location:0.9.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and when I run my app getting this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
> >     present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcg

how can I fix this ???

Comment: can you clean project

Comment: and then add this config to your gradle  :android {
      defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
   }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: Share your gradle console.

Answer (score 0):

replace `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

with `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` like below code

```
    dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'io.nlopez.smartlocation', name: 'library', version: '3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.jota.autocompletelocation:autocomplete-location:0.9.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I do this but I have this problem again :(

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning project did not help, I would suggest you delete these folders

- \build
- .idea
- .gradle
- app\build

then rebuild the project.