# Android studio error: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, zip

When I am trying to build the application I getting error as

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

I went and cleared the JDK. i reinstalled it again but still, I am getting the error. Any have any idea about it?
Thanks in advance

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vicky.sample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Add your build.gradle here .

Comment: ok please wait i'll add

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: Dont just say its is Duplicate look at the question carefully

Comment: and i have tried those solution it didnt work and i have not yet included GMS services in my project

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally solved the problem i just upgraded to Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6 i came across in some thread that this problem is specific to the Android Studio 3.0.1 of intellij platform (i will try to post the thread link later!) but i can not conclude the solution because even i just tried in other thread but i did not got answer yet. And still i am trying to find answer for this thread but for now the current fix is to upgrade the android version.

Answer (score 1):

If you encountered this problem while minifyEnabled true in release you should add this line to your ProGuard-rules.pro file:

```
-keepparameternames
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
multiDexEnabled true

Clean Project.
Rebuild Project
```

Comment: let me know your gradle version?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer but it may possibly help someone. I've had similar issue today after upgrading Android Studio to the next version and compilation failed with the reason java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty. It drove me crazy for the whole day and eventually deleting gradle cashes helped to solve it.

C:\Users\{user}\.gradle\caches

Comment: It freed lots of memo on my SSD buuuut didn't help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding another solution after spending half a day on this. If you have legacy dependencies like citrix or something, they are stored in {user}.m2 instead of {user}.gradle. Delete this directory too if the other solutions are not working!