# Execution failed for task for ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: java, android, dex

hi when i compile my project the error below shows up 
Execution failed for task for  ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

`java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\user\app\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-25.2.0.aar\8bd3003da78946d664f3d05c69c73bfa\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$2.class]))`>

to note  i used  all the answers  from this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

+delete .Gradle  Folder
+Added multiDexEnabled true

but it didn't work for me

my build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.amiapp.candiesstory"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] // レガシー ndk-build サポートを無効にする
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }



dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.8.0'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
}
```

here the project.gradle

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines **and delete** these jar files

```
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```

Your compileSdk is set to 27, not 19, and NineOldAndroids is a deprecated library for several years

You should also find the proper `implementation` dependencies for javax.inject and dagger rather than using jars

You can also remove these repos as jcenter includes Maven Central

```
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Comment: hi , really  thank you  :) !!!
you can make it as answer and thanks again

Comment: hi again sorry for bothering you  just want to ask you if  i replaced **compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')**   with compile **'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'** is this the right way ?