# Unable to merge dex exception

Tags: android-studio, exception, android-multidex

Iv'e suddenly got Unable to merge dex exception (My app worked perfectly until today). Iv'e tried clean and rebuild project with no success, also multiDexEnabled was true even before and still it doesn't work. my dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
//noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)