# android studio 3.0.1 com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.iraklisamniashvilii.com.geoforum"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: It's plenty of this question on SO. Have you done a little search?

Comment: i started search 5 hours ago

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex should have your scenario. Don't stop at the chosen answer, read all the scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: I faced this problem several times. It can be happened because of databinding, same library present, libraries that uses same things but sdk version mismatch.

Comment: how to find out which one ? :/

Comment: for sure you are using firebaseui 2.3.0 with firebase 11.8.0 and that's not good. You have to look at this table: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android. With firebase 11.8.0 you must use firebaseui 3.1.3 or 3.2.2

Comment: you are right problem is solved thank you bro