# Kotlin fails to compile a library

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

There's [this](http://github.com/theapache64/BugMailer) library I created to report exceptions via email. It works well with the Android Java project but fails with Android Kotlin. When I add the compile script for the libary `(compile 'com.theah64.bugmailer:bugmailer:1.1.9')` and tries to build the APK, am getting below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

This is my app's build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.theapache64.calculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.theah64.bugmailer:bugmailer:1.2.0'
}
```

I've googled a lot and tried the `multiDexEnabled` solution. but it doesn't work.

Comment: this may, or may not, be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex

Comment: I've tried all the solution in it. but no help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by conflicting dependencies, 2 of your dependencies are defining the same classes. If you try to compile with

```
./gradlew --stacktrace app:assembleDebug
```

You would see this error

```
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/MagicConstant;
```

Now, you can analyze all the dependency trees with

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

And see these (simplified here):

```
+--- com.theah64.bugmailer:bugmailer:1.2.0
|    +--- org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0
```

and

```
 +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30
 |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
```

So, both Kotlin std lib and bugmailer are using org.jetbrains annotation, but from 2 different modules. This causes a problem because the same class (MagicConstant in that case) is being defined twice, I think that the duplicate entries would be even more.

The solution would be to exclude one of the 2 transitive dependencies, for instance

```
compile('com.theah64.bugmailer:bugmailer:1.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations-java5'
}
```

You will be able to compile the app, but, keep in mind that this solution is based on the assumption that bugmailer will work just fine with `org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0` instead of `org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0`

Comment: Wonderful explanation. (y)

Comment: @theapache64 I just realized that you are the owner of bugmailer isn't it? I might have dropped you an email then loool :)

Comment: haha :D, yeah that's one of my projects. I've fixed the library. Thank you so much.