# Unable To MergeDex After Adding Github Audio Library

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, audio-recording

I looked in other question but no one has my issue, so this is mine:
After Adding Github-audio-library the mergedex error shows up, even after i set "multidex = true", this only happen after adding the audio library.
But after i remove the 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1', the error is gone, so i can't use them both or the error will show up.

the problem is between this two implements :

### =>   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

### =>   implementation 'com.github.axet:android-audio-library:1.0.88'

How to solve it :

```
dependencies {

  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     ////noinspection GradleCompatible
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
  implementation 'com.github.axet:android-audio-library:1.0.88'

}
```

Comment: you can solve it in this answer which i answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402092/4862911

Comment: You mean i should add this :   "configurations.all ......", but i'm not udsing firebase !

Comment: its not only about firebase, if you clearly investigate the code block then you will see that its generic. Anyway if you solve it then there is no problem! @Cristina99

Comment: `implementation 'com.github.axet:android-audio-library:1.0.99'`