# Android merging dex error

Tags: android, merge, android-manifest, manifest, dex

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Hello i am getting the above error please resolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Answer (score 2):

1) Add **multiDexEnabled true** as mention below in app Gradle.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

2) Add the dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

3) call below method in application class

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Hope it will help you !!!

Comment: EC Engineer can do job as An Android developer..awesome.

Comment: Engineer can do anything bro..!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in Gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in app level gradle file..

```
  defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

here you Please Update your build.gradle. and add multidex enable in gadel file.
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

```
     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}`

Answer (score 1):

First Clean your project and build project after

Add **multiDexEnabled true** to your **build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion xx
    defaultConfig {
      ...
        minSdkVersion xx //make sure your minSDK greater than 14 
        targetSdkVersion xx
        multiDexEnabled true
     ...
    }
}
```

finally add dependancy

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```