# How to integrate react-native-fcm on react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase, react-native-fcm

I have implemented `react-native-firebase` in my project. It is working fine. But now I have to get event when the app is opened from the notification tray. According to many blogs and posts I got to know that there is only one solution to get that event through `FCM.on(...) function` and for that you need to install library `react-native-fcm` . But when I install and link it, it started throwing error on android/app/gradle.build file `compile (project(':react-native-fcm'))`. The error I am facing is

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Did you try  multiDexEnabled true https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591042/1679544?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `react-native-fcm`, `react-native-firebase` has all the functionality from `react-native-fcm` built in now. It's all explained quite well in the links below and is quite a bit easier to setup.

[rn-firebase cloud messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/messaging/introduction)

[rn-firebase notifications](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/notifications/introduction)