# After upgrade Play Services to 15.0.0 having MergerException: Unable to merge dex while running

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex

After upgrade Google Play Services to 15.0.0 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex) and also try to add : `multiDexEnabled true` in build.gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50340286/4409113

Comment: Update your question with play services dependencies on manifest file.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท `multiDexEnabled true` May be bad idea if he can use only needed play services modules

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, just delete the `.gradle` file, and then clean your project from `Build > Clean Project`

you can find `.gradle` file in project view in the navigator on the top left

[image]

If you do not enabled `Multidex` follow this link: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Answer (score 0):

You should not include `com.google.android.gms:play-services:...` as a dependency. This adds ALL the Google Play Services APIs to your build and will probably require you to use MultiDex. Instead, follow the directions provided in the [Setup Guid](http://%20https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section titled Selectively compiling APIs into your executable to add as depencies only the specific APIs that you actually use.

But if you feel to use it, you can simple do the following:

Enable `Multidex` through `build.gradle` of your app module

```
multiDexEnabled true
Not Fix my problem. :(
```

Try this :

From the `Build` menu -> press the `Clean` Project button.
When task completed, press the `Rebuild Project` button from the `Build` menu.

`compile` is now deprecated if you are still using it. Use `implementation` or `api`