# Gradle Error suddenly shows up while trying to debug in VSCode and Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I have suddenly run into an error when debugging, it was just working and this error popped up when I tried loading a new screen in main.dart.

### ERROR

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed
  >   Output:  C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:225: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  >   C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:225: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  >   error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a2fedb806fdcf1039dc8366793f0d803\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.lightbridgemobile\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\44d43b22d49402bbb3cf830f8d41ead1\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\44d43b22d49402bbb3cf830f8d41ead1\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a2fedb806fdcf1039dc8366793f0d803\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.lightbridgemobile\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\LightBridge_Mobile\lightbridge_mobile\LightBridge\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

---

Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my own answer from similar SO question ([Android version no longer working after upgrading flutter packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54936122/4794396))

I saw similar errors a few days ago, and found out I needed to upgrade my project to support AndroidX.

I was able to migrate flutter project to support AndroidX without having to use Android studio.

Here's what I did:

1. updated `compileSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file to `28`
2. and `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in gradle.properties

**EDIT**: 
If you see **Unable to merge dex** error, see [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46267621/4794396) that has upvoted solutions including (1) try clean and rebuild OR (2) add following in `app/build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by editing the compileSDK value. I changed it from 27 to 28.