# Android version no longer working after upgrading flutter packages

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter

I just updated a few of my flutter packages. However, I keep getting this error when doing flutter run. If I install the apk directly onto the device, it works fine (meaning I can do flutter build apk), however, no luck with seeing in debug mode.

I initially posted this with a multidex problem which I think I fixed by updating gradle address to 4.3.zip in build.gradle. However, now I have the following issue.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

```
Remos-MBP:tu_chat remobajwa$ flutter run --debug
Launching lib/main.dart on B1 7A0 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1.1s
Resolving dependencies...                                    3.4s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Note: /Users/remobajwa/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/remobajwa/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.2.5+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/remobajwa/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-2.2.0+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java usesor overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/remobajwa/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-0.10.0+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecatedAPI.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/remobajwa/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar/648ac0c7d224ac70bb13139042d8a76b/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

/Users/remobajwa/Desktop/tu_chat/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

/Users/remobajwa/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar/648ac0c7d224ac70bb13139042d8a76b/res/values/values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/remobajwa/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0-beta01.aar/648ac0c7d224ac70bb13139042d8a76b/res/values/values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/Users/remobajwa/Desktop/tu_chat/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/remobajwa/Desktop/tu_chat/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/remobajwa/Desktop/tu_chat/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:237: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/remobajwa/Desktop/tu_chat/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:237: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor406.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
     *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of google_maps_flutter will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s

Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         26.0s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is the my flutter doctor output

```
Remos-MBP:tu_chat remobajwa$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/remobajwa/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/remobajwa/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    ✗ Verify that all connected devices have been paired with this computer in Xcode.
      If all devices have been paired, libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller may require updating.
      To update with Brew, run:
        brew update
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
        brew unlink usbmuxd
        brew link usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • B1 7A0 • 841023849815 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "tuchat.com"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 16      // matching ios version
            versionName flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release

                // minifyEnabled true
                useProguard true

                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
            details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is part of my .build gradle output from the terminal

```
-2).
18:07:49.612 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
18:07:49.612 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
18:07:49.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
18:07:49.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
18:07:49.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/Users/remobajwa/Desktop/tu_chat/android/build.gradle' line: 27
18:07:49.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
18:07:49.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
18:07:49.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
18:07:49.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
18:07:49.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
18:07:49.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
18:07:49.615 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
18:07:49.615 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
18:07:49.615 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

Comment: App works just fine on iOS, so it has something to do with the android files I think, maybe the gradle?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22339386) your question to include version of Flutter (flutter doc info) along with Android SDK version/installed APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar errors a few days ago, and found out I needed to upgrade my project to support AndroidX.

I was able to migrate flutter project to support AndroidX without having to use Android studio.

Here's what I did:

1. updated `compileSdkVersion` in build.gradle file to `28`
2. and `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle.properties`

**EDIT:** If you see **Unable to merge dex** error, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46267621/4794396) that has upvoted solutions including (1) try clean and rebuild OR (2) add following in `app/build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok nice! That worked! but I have a new error now. Does android.useAndroidX=true go in  android/gradle.properties?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex