# How this gradle error will come suddenly?

Tags: java, android

After continuous working many hours i tried to restart my pc.
Than after what i see, whenever i open my project in android studio, it will automatically download gradle 4.4 data. I guess all is ok.
But whenever i run this app in my real device compiler through the exception.
I cant understand how to solve this.
Please tell me immediately.Here i posted 4 images and text of this errors.

[image]

1st

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\vora\Desktop\my_app\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\184, C:\Users\vora\Desktop\my_app\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0
```

2nd

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\vora\Desktop\my_app\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\184, C:\Users\vora\Desktop\my_app\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0
```

3rd

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

4th

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 65760 > 65536)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was succesfully solved by this answer on stackoverflow 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591042/11276659

```
app/build.gradle:

android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```