# Build Failed while run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to run my project on physical device. However while I run android Build failed.
then getting an error.

**Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED**

```js
C:\Users\Alperen\Desktop\AwesomeProject>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 885 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
36 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 34 up-to-date
D8: Program type already present: com.zmxv.RNSound.BuildConfig
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.zmxv.RNSound.BuildConfig
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    
        com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:66)
        ... 11 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: com.zmxv.RNSound.BuildConfig

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D8: Program type already present: com.zmxv.RNSound.BuildConfig
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

NOTE:

I am using 11. verison of jdk.

It's just a hello world project.

yesterday I builded smoothly for apk.

How can I fix that problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: Show your app level gradle

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for handling any Android Studio specific errors is to do a clean+rebuild.

Sometimes the module compilation tend to screw up so running inside your `android` folder should help.

```
rm .idea/modules.xml
rm your-project-name.iml
```

Just make sure you have exited Android Studio before you run those two commands.