# issue with Google Translate in build.gradle

Tags: android, google-translate

Using Android Studio I created a new application - the simple activity.  The generated build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "deanblakely.com.dbatranslator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The project builds properly with this generated build.gradle.  But now I intend on making this project a test project using Google Translate.  I am told by other posts that I should add the following line in the dependencies...

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.6.0'
```

When I try to build again  with this line I get the following...
[image: Errors]

I read that I need this line to use google translate but it is causing all of these errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if u haven't already, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347326/errorconflict-with-dependency-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305