# Getting errors while using Google Cloud Translation Client Libraries for Java (Android)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, google-translate

I'm Trying to make a google translation app using Google's Cloud Translation API. When i'm trying to compile **compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.14.0'** errors as Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties

My android code is as below (No problem in java code)

```
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;

public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();


    String text = "Hello, world!";


    Translation translation =
        translate.translate(
            text,
            TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
            TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru"));


    System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
    System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());
  }
}
```

My build.gradle is as below (problem arrises due to below given **compile** statement)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.googletranslation"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    **compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.14.0'**
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Im getting erros as Below:

- Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (3.0.0) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
- Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
       In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
- Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
       In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
- **I have tried all methods in below link but there is no effect. still errors are increasing**
- [Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347326/errorconflict-with-dependency-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305)

Comment: Help me to make Translation app using Google Translation API

Answer (score 0):

One have to include these:

```
android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'project.properties'
    exclude  'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}


    defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }}
```

}