# Error: Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:multidex' in project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I created a new android project with the following `gradle` file:

```
android {
   ...
   dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
   ...
}

dependencies {
   ...
    compile 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.16.0'
   ...
}
```

But when I build my app I get:

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:multidex' in project
>   ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.0.3) and test app (1.0.1) differ.
>   See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what is your multidex version in your gradle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library/37084656

Comment: @Ankit the version is 1.0.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says you are using 2 versions of `com.android.support:multidex`.Check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37357786/3111083 So in your case it should be

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
}
```

After changing this Clean and rebuild.

Comment: i understand this resolves the issue, but could you explain where is it using multidex version 1.0.1 so that i can update that also?

Comment: @madroid It might be using in any 3rd party libraries you are using. Like in the op's case the multidex was 1.0.1 in mockito.

Comment: ok thanks for the response, i actually ended up keeping version of multidex to 1.0.1 as it was pretty much stable and it got the work done

Answer (score 0):

Mockito depends only on a specific version, so the dependency conflict should be on your side. Do you have any dependencies that depend on specific version? i.e.in your `build.gradle` file. If so, you can try using a [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to force 1.0.3 on them.