# Android studio v2.2.2 error(27,17) failed to resolve junit:junit4.12

Tags: java, android, junit

I have searched everywhere for this answer and tried multiple ways to fix this but as I'm new to this IDE I need a little help.

All I have done is created an empty project in android studio and before I make changes to the files I cant build and keep coming up with 7 errors in my message gradle sync.

> Errors:

1. (27,17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
2. Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
3. Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
4. Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
5. Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
6. Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
7. Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1

This is my project called 'myApplication'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my build gradle module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.app.stannah.com.uk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can someone please tell me what to do to these errors?

Regards

Comment: It's about your connection to internet, try using VPN.

Comment: I dont know how to do this I'm that new im afraid, im on a work proxy which is heavily locked down could that be the reason why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the unwanted libraries from the `build.gradle`,

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and also

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: Hi I have just taken out all the things you have mentioned and came up with all of these errors:

Error:(4, 28) error: package android.support.test does not exist
Error:(5, 35) error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist
Error:(7, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(8, 24) error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
Error:(10, 24) error: package org.junit does not exist

Comment: I have removed all errors after pretty much deleting everything in the exampleunittest.java ... should I have done this?

Comment: You don't need those files, they are only for testing purposes, we have just removed their dependencies, no need to worry at all.

Comment: Thanks alot guys :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `mavenCentral()` to your repositories under `jcenter()` JCenter doesn't have those dependencies that you require.

---

Edit: Also couldn't resolve the dependencies because of the proxy filtering traffic from and to maven.

Comment: in buildscript or all projects?

Comment: @Edgell95 I'm not sure but try both or experiment a little but I think only in `allprojects` may be enough.

Comment: Hi I have added it in both bits but comes up with even more errors now, all my connections are refused, I am on work internet which blocks alot of stuff could this be why or does it have nothing to do with it?

Comment: Might be the reason yeah. Only way to test that is to connect to a public proxy/VPN or disconnect from your work proxy to see if that's the case.

Another thing you may try is to `clean` and then `build` your project again.

Comment: Unfortunately it builds when I connect to personal hotspot on my phone so my company are blocking something, damn it!

Comment: @Edgell95 ouch, that's too bad! Maybe you can request to have those filters removed. At least you now know the cause of the problem. However, you should keep mavenCentral() in your dependencies because that's basically the main repositority for dependencies.

Comment: Yeah I am sending them an email now, and thanks for the tip I will keep maven in there :)

Comment: @Edgell95 you can post an answer to your own question in here stating it was because of your connection to your work's proxy and get this question closed ;)

Comment: How do I get this question closed?

Answer (score 0):

just remove :

> ```
> androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
>     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
> })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

configure proxy then you can able to download

```
javax.inject:javax.inject:1
javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the libraries that is not the way to do.
This issue due to your internet connection.
Set proxy connection in your gradle.properties file

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=hosturl
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.http.proxyPort=portnumber
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password

systemProp.https.proxyHost=hosturl
systemProp.https.proxyPort=portnumber
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
```