# Error in android studio when opening any project

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

When ever I am trying to open any new project or old project I am getting issue such as 
failed to resolve junit
failed to resolve javax.inject 
failed to resolve javax.annotation
 failed to resolve com.google.code.findbugs.
and others. Have tried invalidating , cleaning and even reinstalled android studio nothing works what else to do !

Comment: Remove all unwanted libraries from the gradle
Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396765/android-studio-v2-2-2-error27-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12

Comment: I think you are on a slow LAN. Its taking time to fetch the respective libraries from remote repository and install. Also don't keep unnecessary/unused dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

remove junit dependancy from gridle(module) file or simple install junit library