# Android Studio completely offline

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, offline

I have installed **Android Studio v2.3**. I can't access the internet because  I live in Cuba (Google doesn't accept VPN from my country).

The gradle version required for this version of **Android Studio is 3.3.** I downloaded from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/, configured for offline working and also I downloaded the SDK too. When I created my first project many errors appear:

```
(27,17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
```

I solved them following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40396987. But now the list "API Version in Editor" is null. I resync the project but doesn't work. My question is**`

> Is there a way to have android studio working completely offline?

`** 
I could download the necessary libraries for offline working (via a friend).
PD: In Android Studio 1.x I can work offline without problems, but I want to use the constraint layout, which appears in version 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You will need mirror of maven cetral   repository -   maybe there is some mirror in a cuba itself?  or a country you are allowed to connect to?

Comment: You mean something like this  http://uk.maven.org/maven2/  ? I have access to this site.

Comment: then you can configure it in IDEA / Android studio  as remote maven repository and you shall be fine

Comment: Sorry for the late. In build.gradle I add                                                                 maven {
            url 'uk.maven.org/maven2';
        }                                                                                                                       I want to use ButterKnife library, when I sync project, it says : Could not resolve butterknife. I added in build.gradle (app) the line :                                      compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2' .Is that mean that the library doesnt exists in this mirror?I need to find other mirrors?