# Android studio error after installation (error is in the screenshot)

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: screenshot]

I Just installed Android studio today and i am facing the error as in the screenshot, I don't know what to do there any one who can hel me with this problem?

Comment: Make sure your Gradle settings are not in offline mode when loading the project for the first time.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: all files are not downloaded properly..connect to internet

Comment: Means , how to redownload ?

Comment: is your system connected to internet

Comment: File > Settings > Build, Execution and Deployment > Gradle, Uncheck offline work and use default gradle wrapper

Comment: connect to internet and restart or refresh andoid studio @Jaison_Joseph

Comment: I am pretty sure he is connected since he is replying to us right now...

Comment: If I connect also... Getting the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.2 giving error while creating new project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698082/android-studio-2-2-giving-error-while-creating-new-project)

Comment: Wt to do now ? 

Comment: I have the old version of Android studio in my computer installed, should i uninstall that ?

Comment: If my application contain floating button then only it is showing that error

Answer (score 1):

Update your SDK Manager

```
 Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager in toolbar.
```

By default its showing what are packages to be update  if you want more select the pakages on the list  then update and clean and rebulild the project it will work.

Comment: Sdk is the latest version

Comment: The latest one is SDK Tools, Revision 25.2.5 (Released on January 2017)

Comment: If my application contain floating button then only it is showing that error@sasikumar

Comment: Check your build.gradle file, do you use support design lib version 23.2, like

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
if so, change it to version 23.1.0

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'