# Could not connect to React Native development server on Android

Tags: android, react-native

When I run `react-native run-android`, it gives me the following error:

> Could not connect to development server

[image: Error screen]

- Package server is running and I can access it directly from browser
  on my mobile device.
- My Android device is connected to computer and has debugging enabled (I
  checked using `adb devices` command).
- My Android version is 4.4.4 so I cannot use `adb reverse` command.
- I have set the ID address and port in Dev setting.
- USB debug is on.
- I use Windows 7.

How to fix this error?

Comment: did u look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835931/react-native-adb-reverse-enoent? he run `adb reverse` with android 4.4.2

Comment: but you might have to go with http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi

Comment: Run npm start on local machine to start the development server. I have faced same problem and It worked for me like magic

Comment: Since react native changes so often, would be beneficial to include the react native version as well. Seems like the issue happens on less than 0.59

Comment: http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui is working. wasted lot of time being back of 8081 -- looks like this is updated in later versions. React Native Debugger also keeps looking for 8081, but when you click for a new tab with ctrl-t / cmd-t it suggest 19001 by default. and instead of using chrome developer tools, it seems as a better option

Comment: I was also facing the same issue, for me, I just uninstalled the app from the emulator(Pixel4) & re-run the app again which worked!! Thanks

Answer (score 104, accepted):

From the Docs:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi

Method 2: Connect via Wi-Fi

> You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll
>   first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but
>   once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these
>   instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP
>   address before proceeding.
>
> Open a terminal and type /sbin/ifconfig to find your machine's IP
>   address.
>
> 1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
> 2. Open your React Native app on your device.
> 3. **You'll see a red screen with an error**. **This is OK**. The following steps will fix that.
> 4. Open the in-app Developer menu.
> 5. Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
> 6. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
> 7. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

Comment: Yes,I use Wi-Fi and the mobile device and computer are on the same WIFI network.

Comment: did you follow these commands? any chance you can make a quick screencap and upload as a gif file?

Comment: ok man I am only trying to help ... can you try starting a fresh project with `react-native init myProject` and see if you can connect? so we can eliminate the possibility of the problem being in your code.

Comment: In the future, whenever you are dealing with a new framework / tool, always check fresh installation if you encounter a problem. Will help you find the problem faster AND will save others' people time. good luck mate

Comment: Hey, I can't open the developer menu on my physical device. No amount of shaking on my Galaxy S6 seems to be helping.

Comment: @xerotolerant -- You can hit `adb shell input keyevent 82` on your command-prompt to open the developer-menu.

Comment: Do you know How can I connect my virtual device and my computer same wifi ?
I couldn't select wifi network on virtual device.

Comment: @xerotolerant I know it's old, but for people who have the same problem today, you juste have to shake your phone, and the menu should appear.

Comment: For those who don't know, on Windows you can type `ipconfig` on CMD to find your IPv4 address. That's what you need, plus the port (most likely `:8081`).

Answer (score 171):

Run this and it worked for me

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: From OP: "My android version is 4.4.4 so i cannot use adb reverse command."

Comment: my emulator was connected though it was not getting connected with bundler...this command worked for me

Comment: @Rajat you have to enable it back after this

Comment: It worked, but is this temporary solution or would adb always reverse proxy this port in this emulator?

Comment: It is worker for me/ Sometimes the application do not connect to Metro. I can't understand why.

Comment: My adb path wasn't set correctly and I couldn't use the adb command, but once I fixed that, this solution worked.

Comment: Where it needs to be run? @Yoosaf Abdulla

Comment: in command prompt

Answer (score 150):

In my case the problem was with Android security policies. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted):

> Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

But the application tries to access Metro Bundler through HTTP, right? And that's why it can't. In order to enable cleartext traffic, open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `<application>` node.

For example:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.app"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

You can find more solutions in this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/1673320. OP's problem is different, but similar.

Comment: It's better to apply it only for debug. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55147267/1489446

Comment: If this doesn't work out, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744301/6740333 as new react native versions have a configuration pre-defined

Comment: @ErickM.Sprengel you mentioned this should be applied only for debug. Can there be any issues if this is applied to the main manifest only for `localhost`?

Comment: It'll allow http requests in plain text that are unsafe, if you are aware about it, I think that there is no problem. I'm not sure if some sdks check the NetworkSecurityPolicy.isCleartextTrafficPermitted(), but I think it's not a problem.

Comment: This worked for me on Xiaomi redmi note 6 pro latest android update to the date.

Comment: I was stumped for a few hours with my new Pixel 4a.  I just kept getting the red sceen of death.  None of the other solutions worked for me, I added usesCleartextTraffic and it worked.

Answer (score 61):

> Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is
>   disabled by default.
>       we can use  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" this will work but this is not recommended solution.
>        For **Permanent and recommended Solution** is below:

Step 1 : create a file in android folder
`app/src/debug/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

Step 2 : add this to `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <!-- deny cleartext traffic for React Native packager ips in release -->
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
   <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
   <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
   <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.3.2</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Step 3 : Apply the config to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
</application>
```

Comment: This helped me. Many thanks. I only added 'android:networkSecurityConfig' to /src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: A more general solution is to add all "local" networks:  
`<domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain> 
<domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.0</domain>  
<domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.0.0</domain>  
<domain includeSubdomains="true">172.16.0.0</domain>  
<domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.0</domain>`

Comment: In my case  i have to include gateway and ip address of the genymoation emulator subdomain  in network_security_config.xml . works

Answer (score 24):

This is applicable to Android 9.0+ according to the [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted).
Well, so after trying all possible solutions I found on the web, I decided to investigate the native Android logcat manually. Even after adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, I found this in the logcat:

```
06-25 02:32:34.561 32001 32001 E unknown:ReactNative: Caused by: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.29.96 not permitted by network security policy
```

So, I tried to inspect my react-native app's source. I found that in `debug` variant, there is already a network-security-config which is defined by react-native guys, that conflicts with the `main` variant.

There's an easy solution to this.
Go to `<app-src>/android/app/src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml`
Add a new line with your own IP address in the  like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    ***<domain includeSubdomains="false">192.168.29.96</domain>***
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

As my computer's local IP (check from `ifconfig` for linux) is 192.168.29.96, I added the above line in ***

Then, you need to clean and rebuild for Android!

```
cd <app-src>/android
./gradlew clean
cd <app-src>
react-native run-android
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I spent 3 hours today trying to figure out why my iOS handset worked via USB and Android didn't, even though the Android browser could pull the bundle using the IP:port address. This was the solution. Huge help!

Answer (score 15):

Default metro builder runs on port 8081.
But in my PC, this port is already occupied by some other process (McAfee Antivirus)
So I changed the default running port of metro builder to port number 8088 using the following command

```
react-native run-android start --port=8088
```

This resolved my issue and the app works fine now.

PS: You can check whether a port is occupied or not in windows using "Resource Monitor" app. (Under "Listening Ports" in "Network" tab). Check out this link for detailed explanation: https://www.paddingleft.com/2018/05/03/Find-process-listening-port-on-Windows/

Answer (score 8):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

I just opened Dev menu by clicking `Ctrl+M` and then clicked on `change bundle location` and added my machine IP followed by port.

Comment: Thank you so much, after going through every possible solution this has done the trick, seems like physical devices want to connect to localhost...downsides of not using emulator I guess.

Comment: This did the trick for me, if anyone else is stuck!

Comment: Didn't work for me. This is how I previously resolved said issue, but right now it's not sufficient :( (Android 10, RN 63.3 )

Answer (score 6):

My solution is modify or make new AndroidManifest.xml in android/app/src/debug:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>
```

I am using React Native version: 0.61.5

Comment: I checked Logcat in Android Studio after running on my device, and saw `java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy`. After adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and rebuilding the app, it works.

Answer (score 5):

Solution for React-native `>V0.60`

You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll
first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but
once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these
instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP
address before proceeding.

Open a terminal and type `ipconfig getifaddr en0` For MAC

Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
Open your React Native app on your device.

You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.

1. Open the in-app Developer menu. shake your phone or press `CMD/ctrl + M`
2. Click on Settings
3. click on **Debug server host & port for device**
4. On popup Type your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
5. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload.

**DONE**

Comment: The Developer menu doesn't have Settings

Answer (score 4):

I met this question too in native and react-native pro, my solution was:

1. open npm server with `npm start`
2. run native project with Android Studio
3. transmission network request with `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
4. when you need to reload the page, just input: `adb shell input keyevent 82`

just keep it in order.

P.S. if you ran a fail project, just run `adb kill-server`

Answer (score 4):

** Ubuntu 
Try running these commands both in your root folder only:

1. **sudo npm start**
   --- this will pause automatically after saying -- Loading Graphs, done (something like this) ; when this is done
   -open another terminal
2. **react-native  run-android**

---

If still the issue prevails, delete your build  folder in android / ios
execute this command and then execute the above mentioned commands in the same order

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android**
```

Comment: This will run the app in release mode & not development.

Answer (score 4):

I've added
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and it started working! I've removed it from `main/AndroidManifest.xml` and forgot to add in debug.

ReactNative version is 0.61.2

Comment: I don't have a debug/AndroidManifest.xml file, should it be added?

Comment: @HarryMoreno It was automatically created and stored under `/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: This did it for me as well

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue with Android X device.

For Android API 28 and above

In network_security_config.xml with cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    ....
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then, reload JS

Comment: I'm currently on React Native 0.63 and ran into this issue after adding a custom network_security_config.xml to intercept some traffic with a proxy. With no custom config it seems to work fine on emulators >API 28, but if you add a custom config you will also need to allow cleartext on localhost.

Comment: Thank you for such valuable answer. I am struggling with the hot reload issue since last 2. days. Issue solved because of you. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

What solved the problem for me was to open up android studio, go into AVD manager, actions > Stop and then Cold Boot Now.

Once the device booted up, run `react-native start` and `react-native run-android` as usual.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't think it would, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

> ifconfig

will give you your ip address

copy that Ip address looking something like **192.168.1.100**

> cmd + M

will show the debug menu for android

(in case it doesn't work you can always use the shell)

> adb shell input keyevent 82

Click **Choose Bundle Location** and paste your IP address followed by the port 8081 is the default one...
(should look something like this)

> 192.168.1.100:8081

Click **OK**

Answer (score 3):

To add to `goldylucks`'s answer, you can use IP 192.168.0.10 if that is the IP of your PC running the React Native packager.

You may need to open your firewall as well.

In Ubuntu 18.04, you can get your IP by:

```
ip -c addr show
```

You will see your IP in there, something like: `inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s25` (notice the 192.168.0.10 in my sample).

Then, you could open port 8081 in your firewall, something like:

```
sudo ufw allow 8081
```

It will be using TCP, so make sure TCP is open on port 8081.

Then you can follow goldylucks's answer and goto `Dev settings` and enter `192.168.0.10:8081` or whatever IP you need.

You can test it from the browser on your device. While the packager is running from your PC, navigate to `http://192.168.0.10:8081` from your mobile device and make sure it works. It will show something like "Packager running". It will be clearly working or failing.

Goldylock's answer excites me because it solves the issue very nicely if you are having problems with that error messages. It sucks to have to rebuild the app all the time or worse yet, delete the APK off your device and then build again.

As such, you should probably be using wifi as part of your dev strategy.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest for MAC. Get ip address of your wifi network via `ipconfig getifaddr en0`. Then write that ip to your `DEV settings -> Debug server host & port for device` adding `:8081` 
example. `192.21.22.143:8081`. Then reload. That's it

Comment: where is your Dev settings?

Comment: shake the device or if you use apple simulator `cmd+D`,

Comment: shake the iPhone --> 'configure bundler'

Answer (score 2):

if  adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 this dosent work , You can restart you computer it'll work , because your serve is still running that's wrok form me

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because your Android Virtual Device is not connected to development server. So, check that your Android Virtual Device is connected to internet or not. You can do that by simply checking WiFi connectivity symbol and Mobile Data symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue has happened several times to me already. It's working one minute, and then the next minute it stops working without any change on my part.
The 2nd IP in the error is usually 10.0.2.x instead of 192.x.

I've went through all the answers without being able to resolve the issue.

Ultimately, the one thing that has always worked is to go back to Android Studio, open AVD, and then select the Simulator in question. Do a Duplicate to create another copy of the simulator, and then everything will magically work again.

So my guess is that something inside the simulator folder got corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 solutions for this

- First Solution - Use Adb Command :

  adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

And Rebuild Your Project, And Start Your Metro bundler

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

- Second Solution - Change Bundle Location

Step 1:(MacOS) Command + M(For Android) Command + D(IOS) -Open React-Native Dev menu

Step 2: Change Bundle Location

Step 3: `<ip-address:8081>`

And Rebuild Your Project, And Start Your Metro bundler

```
 npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Hope This Help You !

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug app in your physical android device over wifi using a windows machine, then the device may not be able to access the port of your pc or laptop, you have to make the port accessible. this involves two steps:

1. First create a rule in firewall. for doing this follow the following steps:

   - open run dialog
   - type `wf.msc`
   - click on inbound rules
   - click new rule on right hand side
   - select port from pop up menu and click next
   - select tcp port and specific local ports and enter the port number like `8081` (default)
   - allow the connection
   - select all in profile section
   - give some appropriate name and description
   - click finish
2. you have to make your pc accessible to outside, for doing this follow the following steps:

   - open network and sharing centre from control panel
   - change adapter settings
   - select your wifi network
   - right click, properties
   - click on sharing tab
   - check all the checkboxes

You are good to go, now try running react-native run-android.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure NPM server is running**. Else run it again. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the most upvoted answers and failing to make it work, I figured that my Android Simulator was on Airplane mode. Quite silly but posting this so it could save some time.

P.S. I had a safe reboot on my Simulator before this, which is probably the cause why my simulator booted in Airplane mode

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue on windows by setting the IP address of my local development server in my android device.

Comment: How did you do the set up ?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened when I build from Android Studio instead of the command line using `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a firewall issue. If someone using ubuntu faces this issue , then you can use

```
sudo service iptables stop
```

to disable the firewall for the port to be accessible

Answer (score 0):

and first of all I appreciate you for posting your doubt.
It's mainly because maybe your expo or the app in which you run your react native project may not be in the same local connected wifi or LAN.
Also, there is a chance that there is disturbance in your connection frequently due to which it loses its connectivity.

I too face this problem and I personally clear the cache and then restart again and boom it restarts perfectly.
I hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my emulator has a proxy setting, after turning it off everything works fine.

Comment: How do I turn it off?

Comment: @VikasSatpute which emulator do you use?

Comment: Android Emulator  - Pixel 3 Xl API: 28:5554

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and resolve it by deleting `node module` package and then again install yarn. Simply on some changes we need to clear our.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error comes when npm server is not started.

So at first check the npm server status, if it's not running then start npm with command `npm start` and you can see in terminal:

> Loading dependency graph done.

Now npm is started and run your app in another terminal with command

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

For me i have uninstalled a package that i recently installed and the project ran again on my physical device using the following command "npm uninstall recentPackageName" hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When I started a new project

```
react-native init MyPrroject
```

I got `could not connect to development server` on both platforms `iOS` and `Android`.

My solution is to

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
//find a PID of node
kill -9 <node_PID>
```

Also make sure that you use your local IP address

```
ipconfig getifaddr en0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running on a Macbook, i had to turn off my firewall, thus allowing incoming connections from my android. RN v0.61.5

Answer (score 0):

### RESTART YOUR PHONE

That's all I did and the app bundled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU ARE USING EXPO and it used to connected and suddenly getting the generic error "Something went wrong" many time, with no further hint, meanwhile tried everything else, and the setting are all good, the reason is that your expo running on device does not match anymore with the one on the project, maybe you are running an old project to bump up or similar(I did finally got this message once I tried to connected the app with the direct connection as from docs.

Hope this would help others avoid waist time.

Answer (score -1):

n my case with Android 4.4.2 had to do some additional steps:
(Make sure rn server is running npm start, delete app-debug.apk from android/app/build/outputs/apk , uninstall from android if previously installed and run following commands from root folder)

```
1_ create dir mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2_ create file index.android.js which is a clone of index.js cp index.js index.android.js
3_ react-native link
4_ curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
5_ react-native run-android
```

Comment: No, Your step didn't work. Firstly I got "Unexpected token >" error and when I reload app then It gave "Couldn't connect to development server"

Answer (score -1):

If did not work all of these answer's just delete the `node_modules/` and `npm i --save`

Answer (score -1):

Just open cmd/powershell, and inside your project directory run the following command

```
react-native start
```

Answer (score -3):

We faced this issue, In order to fix this, solution is dead simple is below.

1. Cancel the current process of“react-native run-android” by CTRL + C
   or CMD + C
2. Close metro bundler window command line which opened
   automatically.
3. Run the command again, “react-native run-android”.

> Basically this error tells that your current build got failed due to reasons like Code issue or dependency issue.

[Click here for more details](https://medium.com/error-healer/react-native-could-not-connect-to-development-server-2b39c7f15ddc)